# HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git

Tags: git, git-head

What do these symbols refer to and what do they mean?

(I can't find any explanation in official documentation)

Comment: Note: `HEAD` is now (upcoming git1.8.4) '`@`'! See [my edited answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309)

Comment: Note-bis: '`@`' (for `HEAD`) is still coming, but not for 1.8.4 [answer edited and amended](http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309).

Comment: Note ter: '`@`' for `HEAD` is back for git 1.8.5/1.9. [answer edited again](http://stackoverflow.com/a/964927/6309).

Comment: `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD` in Git are like `$PWD` and `$OLDPWD` in Bash. :)

Comment: I find that `HEAD` is not identical to `@` when running `git checkout`. In addition, I also find that `HEAD` is not identical to `HEAD~0` when running `git checkout`. In fact, `@` is identical to `HEAD~0`. The following screenshots are as follows: [`@` vs `HEAD`](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8049878/97380804-c3c48f80-1902-11eb-9b1f-c0e84c281808.png) and [`HEAD` vs `HEAD~0`](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8049878/97381118-5a914c00-1903-11eb-8599-d215fc21885d.png)

Answer (score 372, accepted):

`HEAD` is (direct or indirect, i.e. symbolic) reference to the current commit. It is a commit that you have checked in the working directory (unless you made some changes, or equivalent), and it is a commit on top of which "git commit" would make a new one. Usually `HEAD` is symbolic reference to some other named branch; this branch is currently checked out branch, or current branch. `HEAD` can also point directly to a commit; this state is called "detached HEAD", and can be understood as being on unnamed, anonymous branch.

And **`@`** alone is a shortcut for `HEAD`, since Git 1.8.5

[`ORIG_HEAD`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) is previous state of `HEAD`, set by commands that have possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them. It is less useful now that Git has reflog: `HEAD@{1}` is roughly equivalent to `ORIG_HEAD` (`HEAD@{1}` is always last value of `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD` is last value of `HEAD` before dangerous operation).

For more information read [git(1) manpage](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git.html) / [gitrevisions(7) manpage][git-revisions], [Git User's Manual](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html), the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/) and [Git Glossary](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitglossary.html)

Comment: Hi Jakub. +1 for the explanation. Could you detail the "roughly equivalent" part of HEAD@{1} ? I refer in my answer to the thread http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/38379 (you were in it, back in February 2007), and I did not exactly understood the discussion you guys were having around the @{...} syntax.

Comment: ORIG_HEAD is set (I think) only by 'dangerous' commands, that move HEAD more than one commit. So ORIG_HEAD is not always set, while HEAD@{1} is always set. @{1} is $(git symbolic-ref HEAD)@{1}, i.e. it is uses reflog for current branch, not HEAD reflog.

Comment: @RJFalconer: I don't know if Git dicumentation that was on kernel.org would go back - access is now much more strict.  Try links from Git Homepage (Documentation section).

Comment: "and HEAD is a commit on top of which "git commit" would make a new one. " -- good to remember, thanks! Also from @VonC, 'It is the commit "git commit" builds on top of, and "git diff --cached" and "git status" compare against.'

Comment: git help revisions brings up http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions, which describes all the ways to reference commits (including `HEAD` and `ORIG_HEAD`).

Comment: `git show ORIG_HEAD` is a good sanity check before using that revision in a command

Comment: In some cases, `HEAD` is not identical to `@`. [Here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/8049878/97380804-c3c48f80-1902-11eb-9b1f-c0e84c281808.png) are a bunch of screenshots.

Comment: @liuliang - it looks like in this case there is a tag named `@`, which probably shouldn't be allowed. https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions says explicitly *"@ alone is a shortcut for HEAD"*

Comment: I always assumed that this was the `HEAD` of the last fetch from the `origin` remote… :)

Answer (score 128):

### `ORIG_HEAD`

From [git reset](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)

> "pull" or "merge" always leaves the original tip of the current branch in **`ORIG_HEAD`**.
>
> ```
> git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
> ```
>
> Resetting hard to it brings your index file and the working tree back to that state, and resets the tip of the branch to that commit.
>
> ```
> git reset --merge ORIG_HEAD
> ```
>
> After inspecting the result of the merge, you may find that the change in the other branch is unsatisfactory. Running "`git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD`" will let you go back to where you were, but it will discard your local changes, which you do not want. "`git reset --merge`" keeps your local changes.

---

> Before any patches are applied, ORIG_HEAD is set to the tip of the current branch.
> This is useful if you have problems with multiple commits, like running '`git am`' on the wrong branch or an error in the commits that is more easily fixed by changing the mailbox (e.g. +errors in the "From:" lines).
>
> In addition, merge always sets '`.git/ORIG_HEAD`' to the original state of HEAD so a problematic merge can be removed by using '`git reset ORIG_HEAD`'.

---

Git 2.40 (Q1 2023) documents `ORIG_HEAD` a bit more:

See [commit f1c9243](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1c9243fc5e5234ed00d3ecb71f2629c18d791ab), [commit c6eec9c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2), [commit 0c514d5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0c514d576685f72a42cf60a2690984fbc7f54a31), [commit d03c773](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d03c773cf6c9d425a8d25af7a45775e280fd6d81), [commit e29678b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e29678bb7c967f731965829e38aab8dd88e5c031) (10 Jan 2023) by [Philippe Blain (`phil-blain`)](https://github.com/phil-blain).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9c2003a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c2003a6cb99a8aa5aeb7c311247456264799f7f), 21 Jan 2023)</sup>

> ### [`git-rebase.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f1c9243fc5e5234ed00d3ecb71f2629c18d791ab): add a note about '`ORIG_HEAD`' being overwritten
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Erik Cervin Edin</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> '`ORIG_HEAD`' is written at the start of the rebase, but is not guaranteed to still point to the original branch tip at the end of the rebase.
>
> Indeed, using other commands that write '`ORIG_HEAD`' during the rebase, like splitting a commit using '[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f1c9243fc5e5234ed00d3ecb71f2629c18d791ab/Documentation/git-reset.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup> HEAD^', will lead to '`ORIG_HEAD`' being overwritten.
> This [causes confusion for some users](https://lore.kernel.org/git/28ebf03b-e8bb-3769-556b-c9db17e43dbb@gmail.com/T/#m827179c5adcfb504d67f76d03c8e6942b55e5ed0).
>
> Add a note about that in the 'Description' section, and mention the more robust alternative of using the branch's reflog.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f1c9243fc5e5234ed00d3ecb71f2629c18d791ab/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L41-L47):

> `[NOTE]`:
> `ORIG_HEAD` is not guaranteed to still point to the previous branch tip
> at the end of the rebase if other commands that write that pseudo-ref
> (e.g. `git reset`) are used during the rebase.
> The previous branch tip, however, is accessible using the reflog of the current branch (i.e. `@{1}`).

And:

> ### [`revisions.txt`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2): be explicit about commands writing '`ORIG_HEAD`'
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Philippe Blain</sup>
> <sup>Acked-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> When mentioning '`ORIG_HEAD`', be explicit about which command write that pseudo-ref, namely '[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2/Documentation/git-am.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup>, '[`git merge`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2/Documentation/git-merge.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge))</sup>, '[`git rebase`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2/Documentation/git-rebase.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase))</sup> and '[`git reset`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2/Documentation/git-reset.txt)'<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset))</sup>.

`revisions` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/c6eec9cb3677fe91c887181c0a184cb30627fca2/Documentation/revisions.txt#L52-L53):

> `ORIG_HEAD` is created by commands that move your `HEAD` in a drastic
> way (`git am`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, `git reset`),
> to record the position of the `HEAD` before their operation, so that
> you can easily change the tip of the branch back to the state before you ran them.

---

### `HEAD`

Note: from [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.version-control.git/38379)

> HEAD is a moving pointer.  Sometimes it means the current branch, sometimes it doesn't.
>
> So HEAD is *NOT* a synonym for "current branch" everywhere already.
>
> HEAD means **"current" everywhere** in git, but it does not necessarily mean "current branch" (i.e. detached HEAD).
>
> But it almost always means the "current commit".
> It is the commit "`git commit`" builds on top of, and "`git diff --cached`" and "`git status`" compare against.
> It means the current branch only in very limited contexts (exactly when we want a branch
> name to operate on --- resetting and growing the branch tip via commit/rebase/etc.).
>
> Reflog is a vehicle to go back in time and time machines have interesting interaction with the notion of "current".
>
> `HEAD@{5.minutes.ago}` could mean "dereference HEAD symref to find out what branch we are on RIGHT NOW, and then find out where the tip of that branch was 5 minutes ago".
> Alternatively it could mean "what is the commit I would have referred to as HEAD 5
> minutes ago, e.g. if I did "git show HEAD" back then".

---

[git1.8.4 (July 2013)](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/1.8.4.txt#L201-202) <del>introduces</del> **introduced** a new notation!
(Actually, it will be for 1.8.5, Q4 2013: reintroduced with [commit 9ba89f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba89f484e023827eca6ad44baf69af37dac4db3)), by [**Felipe Contreras**](https://twitter.com/felipec).

> Instead of typing four capital letters "`HEAD`", you can say "`@`" now,
> e.g. "`git log @`".

See [commit cdfd948](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cdfd94837b27c220f70f032b596ea993d195488f)

> Typing '`HEAD`' is tedious, especially when we can use '`@`' instead.
>
> The reason for choosing '`@`' is that it follows naturally from the `ref@op` syntax (e.g. `HEAD@{u}`), except we have no ref, and no operation, and when we don't have those, it makes sens to assume '`HEAD`'.
>
> So now we can use '`git show @~1`', and all that goody goodness.
>
> Until now '`@`' was a valid name, but it conflicts with this idea, so let's make it invalid. Probably very few people, if any, used this name.

Comment: After running git reset ORIG_HEAD and commit. ORIG_HEAD is still there under References next to HEAD. Why was it not removed from the view?

Comment: @powder366 but a `git reset` will generate a `ORIG_HEAD`. So you need to `rm` it manually. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12418078/6309 for instance.

Comment: @VonC the `@` alias for `HEAD` is being [reverted (temporarily?) for the Git 1.8.4 release](http://git-blame.blogspot.com/2013/08/delaying-git-184-by-week.html)! It was just announced today!

Comment: Enjoyed the "heads-up" comment!

Comment: @snakecharmerb Yes, as this answer above states, `@ alone is a shortcut for HEAD` dates from Git 1.8.5 and [commit 9ba89f4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9ba89f484e023827eca6ad44baf69af37dac4db3), Q3 2013.

Comment: @snakecharmerb Good point. I have removed the revert part, to keep only the announcement.

Answer (score 5):

From [`man 7 gitrevisions`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions):

> HEAD names the commit on which you based the changes in the
> working tree.  FETCH_HEAD records the branch which you fetched
> from a remote repository with your last git fetch invocation.
> ORIG_HEAD is created by commands that move your HEAD in a
> drastic way, to record the position of the HEAD before their
> operation, so that you can easily change the tip of the branch
> back to the state before you ran them.  MERGE_HEAD records the
> commit(s) which you are merging into your branch when you run
> git merge.  CHERRY_PICK_HEAD records the commit which you are
> cherry-picking when you run git cherry-pick.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that HEAD points the current branch, while ORIG_HEAD is used to store the previous HEAD before doing "dangerous" operations.

For example git-rebase and git-am record the original tip of branch before they apply any changes.

Comment: HEAD does not always point on the current branch (it can be detached)

Comment: So what is the "current branch" when HEAD is "detached?"

Comment: @CurtJ.Sampson That is  "no branch".  that's why when you in detached head , you do `git branch foo -b` in order to "create" a branch for that orphans commits.