# How to get aliases working in .gitconfig?

Tags: git, alias

[Github](http://github.com/guides/git-cheat-sheet) has the following recommendation for global git configuration `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]             # Is this [-] only a comment in .gitconfig?
gb = git branch
gba = git branch -a
gc = git commit -v
gd = git diff | mate  
gl = git pull
gp = git push
gst = git status
```

The above commands worked in my old Git.
However, they do not work now for some unknown reason.

The problem seems not to be in the commands. It is perhaps in another git related file which controls which file affects aliases.

**How can you get the aliases to work?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe what GitHub is referring to is *system aliases*, not '.gitconfig' aliases.

In other terms, you would need to type, like [illustrated here](http://robsanheim.com/2008/04/04/zero-to-a-fully-git-enabled-rails-app-in-the-time-it-takes-to-drink/#aliases), the following *Unix* command to make those 'aliases' work:

```
alias g=’git’
alias gb=’git branch’
alias gba=’git branch -a’
alias gc=’git commit -v’
alias gca=’git commit -v -a’
alias gd=’git diff | mate’
alias gl=’git pull’
alias gp=’git push’
```

Answer (score 22):

The first thing to be aware of is that the git aliases only apply when you are calling git, so an alias of `st = status` will take effect when you run:

```
$ git st
```

If you want to be able to do:

```
$ gst
```

To run `git status` you would need to set up an alias for bash (or whatever shell you use).

Well, for aliases which are simply shorter versions of git commands (like `st` for `status`), you do not need to add the `git` prefix to it. Additionally, if you want to execute a shell command rather than a git sub-command, you must prefix the alias definition with an exclamation point, as specified in `git-config(1)`. My alias section of my `~/.gitconfig` looks like this:

```
[alias]
    st = status
    ci = commit -s
    br = branch
    co = checkout
    vis = !gitk --all &
```

And then I can run:

```
$ git st # Runs "git status"
$ git ci # Runs "git commit -s"
$ git vis # runs "gitk --all &"
```

And so on.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orighead-in-git

I should probably change it, but I don't actually ever use "git new", so I never noticed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, i navigated to .zsh folder and cloned this repo as `git clone https://github.com/mdumitru/git-aliases.git` , then `source ~/.zshrc`  and is worked.