# How do I make git alias for 'git gc' work

Tags: git

For some reason I have to run git `gc --prune=now` almost every day before I run a `git pull` so I wanted to create a `git pp` alias that helps me run those two commands

I added this to the users .gitconfig file

```
[alias]
    pp = 'gc --prune=now && pull'
```

but when I try to run it I get what it seems a sintax error, how do I fix this on windows 10

[image]

I have read this

- [How to get aliases working in .gitconfig?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060963/how-to-get-aliases-working-in-gitconfig)
- [Syntax for Git aliases with multiple commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18860696/syntax-for-git-aliases-with-multiple-commands)

but I dont see my mistake

Comment: You could also just create a script file named `git-pp` with the commands as separate lines. They will be executed by bash so they need to mention git though.

Comment: I actually thought about that approach too, but whant to learn what I'm doing wrong here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `!` at start to indicate that bash has to execute the alias, not git itself.

Then, explicitly call git for your pull command :

```
git config alias.pp '!git gc --prune=now && git pull'
```

To use it in the .gitconfig file make sure you use double quotes ""

```
[alias] 
    pp = "!git gc --prune=now && git pull"
```

Comment: I have set it to  `pp = '!git gc --prune=now && git pull'` as you mention, and still getting the same error, maybe my configuration is wrong ? Do I have to close the git command line everytime I save the .gitconfig ?

Comment: @MauricioGraciaGutierrez : the quotes are meant for the command line, not for the config file. Do you have quotes around your alias in your config file ?

Comment: LeGEC is right, this is probably a confusion because of the first draft of my answer, I should have explicitly used the `git config` command syntax.