# Is there a difference between git reset --hard HEAD and git checkout .?

Tags: git, revert

If I make changes to the working tree and have not yet committed, and I would like to revert the changes I have made, is there a difference between

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

and

```
git checkout .
```

?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "git reset --hard hash" and "git checkout hash"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541545/is-there-a-difference-between-git-reset-hard-hash-and-git-checkout-hash)

Comment: This is a nice (and thorough) explanation by the author of the Pro Git book: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Reset-Demystified

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`git checkout -- .` will obviously only work on the current directory (and subdirectories thereof), `git reset --hard` will operate on the complete working tree.

`git checkout -- .` will only update the working tree and leave already staged files as is, whereas `git reset --hard` will match index and working tree with the HEAD commit.

when used with a refspec:

1. `reset` will set the current branch head to the given commit (and matches index and working tree)
2. `checkout` will switch to that branch, leaving local changes intact, when they touch files which did not change between the current branch and the branch to be checked out

Comment: git checkout -- . seems to be clearing out the staging area as well. I am not sure about the first point as I always work out of the root directory.

Comment: @Moondra I just tried again with Git 2.24 and I cannot confirm your statement. `git checkout` leaves the staging area untouched, so already-staged files will remain staged.

Comment: Actually it seems `git checkout HEAD -- .`  clears the staging area. I actually made a separate thread on it as I thought they were the same. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59339986/is-there-a-difference-between-git-checkout-head-and-git-reset-hard-head/59340544#59340544

But you are right. I was using HEAD. Sorry

Answer (score 5):

These answers are good.  I'd like to add that if you have deleted files, which are staged but not yet committed, then a git `checkout .` alone will not bring the deleted files back into the workspace.  A `git reset --hard` will.