# Is there a difference between git checkout HEAD -- . and git reset --hard HEAD?

Tags: git

I have taken a look at this stackoverflow link but I think the subtle difference between what I am asking is the usage of `HEAD` within the checkout cmd as their suggestions don't' seem to be working :

[Is there a difference between git reset --hard HEAD and git checkout .?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5128806/is-there-a-difference-between-git-reset-hard-head-and-git-checkout)

`git checkout HEAD -- .` cleans out my staging area as well.
Additionally, the second answer, regarding deleted files added to staging area,
seem to be coming back with `git checkout HEAD -- .`

Is there a situation where one would get different results?

Comment: 1. It's not `head`, it's `HEAD`, and the difference is important. 2. `git checkout -- .`  is completely equivalent to `git checkout HEAD -- .`; having this in mind your question is an exact dup of the linked q.

Comment: @phd checkout with `HEAD` and without it are not doing exactly the same thing. For example `git checkout -- .` will not bring back a deleted file that has already been staged, but `git checkout HEAD -- .` will bring such a file back.

Comment: @FlyingFoX Ok, without explicit `HEAD` git checks files out from the index.

Comment: @phd I've edited the `head` portion. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference, besides that implied by `.` if you're not at the top level of your repository.  I won't go so far as to claim that what follows is the *only* difference; it suffices to show one example, to see that they are different.

#### Set-up for illustrating a difference

Start by creating a new repository with at least one commit (here I have made two, as is my habit):

```
$ mkdir treset
$ cd treset
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in ...
$ echo 'for testing reset vs checkout' > README
$ git add README
$ git commit -m 'initial commit'
[master (root-commit) 058b755] initial commit
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ echo contents for file a > file-a
$ echo contents for file b > file-b
git commit -m 'add files'
[master f505609] add files
 2 files changed, 2 insertions(+)
 create mode 100644 file-a
 create mode 100644 file-b
```

At this point, `HEAD` and the index match—both contain the content from commit `f505609`—and the work-tree contains the (normal format) files that match that commit as well.  Now let's add a *new* file, and copy it into the index:

```
$ echo 'uncommitted file' > foo
$ git add foo
```

Technically, the `git add foo` created *blob object* `a9e2570d6af8c05b57e2cefecaebeedfabc98bf2` in the repository and then put that hash ID into the index:

```
$ git ls-files --stage
100644 e16f62b2e75cf86a6f54adcfddcfd77140f238b9 0       README
100644 881d9334f4593efc7bab0dd536348abf47efed5c 0       file-a
100644 fa438bc26ce6b7a8f574bad9e63b83c912a824b9 0       file-b
100644 a9e2570d6af8c05b57e2cefecaebeedfabc98bf2 0       foo
```

(The hash ID of this blob object is predictable due to the known content for file `foo`.  That's true of the other three files as well, but they're actually committed, so those blob objects are permanent.  The one for `foo` could be GCed, if we never actually commit it and instead remove the entry from the index.)

#### Using `git checkout HEAD`

If we use `git checkout HEAD`, we direct Git to *copy* from `HEAD` into the index and then expand them into normal work-tree files.  `HEAD` contains three files (`README`, `file-a`, and `file-b`), so this does that and updates the three work-tree files with the contents they already have—so there's no observable effect.<sup>1</sup>

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- .; ls
file-a  file-b  foo README
```

Note that file `foo` remains, both in the index (run `git ls-files` again to see) and in the work-tree.

---

<sup>1</sup>Unless, that is, we inspect things like file modification times or system calls executed, via whatever OS-level tools we have available.  In this case we can tell if Git really did overwrite the work-tree files or not.  On my system, it actually *didn't*, because the index hashes matched the `HEAD` hashes and the `stat` data cached in the index matched the `stat` data from the work-tree files, so it didn't bother.  But in *principle* Git copied `HEAD` to the index, and then the index to the work-tree, and if it were necessary based on hashes and/or stat data, Git would have actually touched the work-tree files here.

---

#### Using `git reset --hard`

If we tell Git to reset the index to match the current commit, and reset the work-tree to match changes to the index, the action is different.  This time, Git examines the index and sees that file `foo` is present, while it's absent in the commit.  So Git *removes* file `foo` *from* the index, and updates the work-tree accordingly:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD; ls
HEAD is now at f505609 add files
file-a  file-b  README
```

File `foo` has vanished from the work-tree.

If we were to use `git reset --mixed HEAD`, Git would remove `foo` from the index, but not from the work-tree.  (The default action for this kind of reset—there are many other kinds—is `--mixed`.)

#### Using `git restore`

With the new Git 2.23+ `git restore` command, we can control the index and work-tree separately.  First we have to put `foo` back into the index and work-tree:

```
$ echo 'uncommitted file' > foo
$ git add foo
```

We can now choose whether to copy `HEAD` to the index or not, and whether to manage the work-tree similarly.  [Its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) is a bit more explicit too:

> If a path is tracked but does not exist in the restore source, it will be removed to match the source.

What it means for a path to be "tracked" is that the path is in the index.  In this case, `foo` is in the index now (due to the `git add`) so it is tracked.  If we restore the index from `HEAD`, `foo` will be removed from the index, just as with `git reset --hard` or `git reset --mixed`.  So let's try [VonC's command](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59340290/1256452), but with `.` (the current directory and all sub-directories)<sup>2</sup> as the pathname, here:

```
$ git restore --source HEAD --staged --worktree .
$ ls
file-a  file-b  README
```

So you can see that this had the same effect as `git reset --hard`.  Unlike `git reset`, `git restore` has only one job—though with two parts to it—so we need not worry about other modes of operation.

(This is why both `git switch` and `git restore` were added: the mostly do the *same things* you can already do with `git checkout` and `git reset`, but they only have *one* job, even if it has several parts.  By contrast, `git checkout` has anywhere from about three to about seven different jobs, depending on how you count, and `git reset` has anywhere from about three to about five.<sup>3</sup>)

---

<sup>2</sup>This particular repository has only the one top level directory, so we need not worry that you've done a `cd subdir` within the work-tree.  If you had, though, `.` would mean *apply this to the `subdir/*` files*, so that checkout and reset would be even more different.

<sup>3</sup>For `git checkout`, consider:

- switch branches
- extract from index to work-tree (only, a la `git checkout-index`)
- extract from specific commit to index and then on to work-tree
- reproduce merge conflict (`git checkout -m` with a file name)
- switch branches while merging (`git checkout -m` but with a branch name)

While that's just five, we can `git checkout --ours` and `git checkout --theirs` and some might wish to count these as separate from the usual "extract from index" flavor.  We can get even more when you add *create branch* (`git checkout -b`) and *forcibly reset branch* (`git checkout -B`).  Alas, `git switch` has the create and forcibly-reset options as well!

Some might, of course, lump some or all of these into one operation, just as `git checkout` does.  That's why I say "depending on how you count".

For `git reset`, consider:

- reset index and/or work-tree without moving `HEAD`
- reset index and/or work-tree *with* moving `HEAD`
- reset one or more specific paths (cannot move `HEAD`)
- abort a merge or cherry-pick or revert (cannot move `HEAD`)
- selectively patch with `git reset -p` (cannot move `HEAD`)

all of which are lumped under the one command `git reset`.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid the [confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309), you should use the new experimental command **[`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore)** (Gti 2.23+, August 2019).

As I explained in "[What is `git restore` Command ? What is the different between `git restore` and `git reset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58003889/6309)", you can specify what to restore with `git restore`.

- the index
- and/or the working tree.

This is more explicit than relying on HEAD or no HEAD in `git checkout`.

To do a `reset --hard` with `git restore`:

```
git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree hello.c
```

or the short form, which is more practical but less readable:

```
git restore -s@ -SW hello.c
```