# "git checkout tag-name" vs "git reset --hard tag-name"

Tags: git

I know that there are questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541545/is-there-a-difference-between-git-reset-hard-hash-and-git-checkout-hash), but that's not what I'm asking.

I also know that:

`git checkout tag-name`:

- Detaches you from the branch. (i.e. moves `HEAD` pointer, keeps `BRANCH` pointer)

`git reset --hard tag-name`:

- Does not detach you from the branch, but makes the previous commits to become "dangling". (i.e. moves both `HEAD` and `BRANCH` pointers)

I wonder which one makes more sense for updating to a tag, i.e. should a production be reseted or checked out. I know that a garbage collector may run, removing dangling commits, but then again, if the production is always "pulled" before the process of updating to a tag, I see nothing bad there.

Should a production update to a tag with `reset` or `checkout`, considering that a `pull` is always done prior to this update call?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> I wonder which one makes more sense for updating to a tag

Your production install should be checking out a tag.

Think of it this way: your production install is read-only. `git reset --hard tag-name` will modify the currently checked out branch.

**Alternatively**

It's common practice that in addition to creating a tag, you have one branch which is simply the latest release. In which case you'd e.g. merge to master and create a tag from there; and on your production installs you'd update simply with git pull (on master).