# git commands as hg commands

Tags: git, merge, mercurial

I had worked with Mercurial but now working with Git. I have some difficulty with understanding Git, can you help me, what are the alternatives to Git commands like Mercurial:

```
hg up -C 
hg revert --all 
hg purge
```

If I have some conflicts from the Mercurial command "`hg up`", I can run commands like `hg revert --all & hg purge` or `hg up -C`.

What can I do after `git pull` and file conflicts if I don't want to continue, but just  revert to the original state, or update files without conflicts (like `hg up -C`)?

Answer (score 5):

You can refer to [Git hg rosetta stone](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/wiki/Git-hg-rosetta-stone)

For example:

```
hg update -C    git checkout -f 
hg revert -a    git reset --hard 
hg purge        git clean -fd
```

So see:

- [`git checkout` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)
- [`git reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)
- [`git clean` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean)

Also:

- "[What's the difference between “`git reset`” and “`git checkout`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639342/6309)".
- "[Is there a difference between “`git reset --hard hash`” and “`git checkout hash`”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2541545/6309)"

And finally: "[Undo git pull, how to bring repos to old state](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1223354/6309)"

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I tried to follow your advice. After command `git reset --hard` all changes are discarded, then I run command `git checkout -f` and got next message http://screencloud.net/v/x2p5 Then I check file changes and new changes are not applied. After then I run command `git status` and got message http://screencloud.net/v/8Dl9/. then I run command `git pull` again, I got conflicts again =(((( It is confuse, because if I have clean working directory I can run command `hg pull` without conflicts, But if I run `git pull` I got conflicts

Comment: For your `git checkout -f` error message, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/2452610/6309

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do after "git pull" and file's conflicts, if I don't want to continue, but just revert to the original state

When you do a `git pull`, you are really doing a `git fetch` followed by either a `git merge` *or* a `git rebase`.  Assuming your pull strategy is using merge, then your question is how can you undo the merge done during a `git pull`.  One clean way to undo a merge is to reset your local branch to the latest commit:

```
git reset --hard <SHA-1 hash of latest commit>
```

> What can I do ... update files without conflicts (like hg up -C)

When you do a `git pull`, you bring in the changes to *all* the files from the remote branch.  Usually you would not want to update only files which have no conflicts.  Git is a *workspace*-based version control system, as opposed to something like SVN, which is a *file*-based VCS.

If you *really* want to try doing a `git pull` and then update only files which are not in conflict, then you can use the following command to identify which files have conflicts:

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=U
```

Then for each file in the list, you can do a `git reset` on it:

```
git checkout -- filename_in_conflict
```

Comment: Were you looking for a way to map Mercurial commands, or info on how to actually execute in Git?

Comment: I don't understand Git =( If I run `hg pull & hg up -C` I always get the actual code in working directory without conflicts, But `git fetch & git checkout -f` is not `hg pull & hg up -C`. If I run command `git checkout -- filename_in_conflict` I got message http://screencloud.net/v/scPD

Comment: My advice is to you is to post a new question where you specify _exactly_ what you are trying to do in Git.  You will get an answer that can get you started.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. here is my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33255900/git-how-to-update-the-working-directory-like-hg-up-c-in-mercurial