# How to uncommit my last commit in Git

Tags: git, undo, git-reset, git-index

How can I uncommit my last commit in git?

Is it

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

or

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

?

Comment: For git I find that the man page is often the best reference (or alternatively, `git help reset`)

Comment: Please check here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130829/7178104

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD~1 
will reset only last git commit, not reset your files changes

Comment: If this happens to be your first commit, try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911317/how-to-remove-the-first-commit-in-git

Answer (score 2264):

If you aren't totally sure what you mean by "uncommit" and don't know if you want to use `git reset`, please see "[Revert to a previous Git commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114095/119963)".

If you're trying to understand `git reset` better, please see "[Can you explain what "git reset" does in plain English?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english)".

---

If you know you want to use `git reset`, it still depends what you mean by "uncommit". If all you want to do is undo the act of committing, leaving everything else intact, use:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

If you want to undo the act of committing and everything you'd staged, but leave the work tree (your files) intact:

```
git reset HEAD^
```

And if you actually want to *completely* undo it, ***throwing away all uncommitted changes, resetting everything to the previous commit*** (as the original question asked):

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

---

The original question also asked it's `HEAD^` not `HEAD`. `HEAD` refers to the current commit - generally, the tip of the currently checked-out branch. The `^` is a notation which can be attached to *any* commit specifier, and means "the commit before". So, `HEAD^` is the commit before the current one, just as `master^` is the commit before the tip of the master branch.

Here's the portion of the [git-rev-parse documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/1/git-rev-parse) describing all of the ways to specify commits (`^` is just a basic one among many).

Comment: Re: "answers neglect to mention why it's HEAD^ not HEAD, which was the original question" - this seems wrong: the original question was not actually asking "why", just "which one is it"..  It's nevertheless helpful to have more background than less.

Comment: @Jefromi: every answer in this question is totally wrong to emphasize --hard, the --soft,  is necessary for it to be "uncommit last commit", a --hard will not only uncommit but also destroy your commit. I nearly destroyed a whole day's of work since I didn't recheck what --hard meant assuming 70+ answer wouldn't be wrong. Fortunately reflog saved my day, but it wouldn't have to be that way.

Comment: @jameshfisher It's the answer to the original question ("which of these two is it?") and there was a giant warning right underneath it. I'm editing, but... if you see a question that looks from the title like what you want, and you just blindly run the first command you see in the first answer, *this is going to keep happening to you*.

Comment: `get reset --soft HEAD^` is what i was looking for!!! SO sweet, what is the term for putting changes into the current working head? or directory.

Comment: `git reset HEAD^` gives me `zsh: no matches found: HEAD^`, but `git reset HEAD~1` works

Comment: Note for zsh users: use `git reset 'HEAD^'`

Comment: @Cascabel, would you mind to add to the `git reset --soft HEAD^` that the changes remain staged? I think that beginners might get confused between the `soft` and the default (`mixed`) option.  I would edit it myself, but I am not 100% sure this is the case.

Comment: @Cascabel, I was thinking that the source of the confusion migh come from the message that appears when changes are staged, `git status` is typed which is `use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage`. The message is correct, but since changes are not yet commited, then `HEAD` should be used instead of `HEAD^`. Maybe, you would like to clarify that, otherwise somebody could conclude that resetting to the HEAD is always pointless.

Comment: What if your only commit local is the first commit?git reset --soft "HEAD^"
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD^': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'

Comment: When I type `git reset --hard HEAD^`, it asks `More?`, then I type `y`, and it says `fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEADy': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: Use   HEAD^^   if you using Windows

Comment: @EugeneMaksimov `git reset --hard "HEAD^"` works too for Windows

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD^ worked for me

Answer (score 656):

`git reset --soft HEAD^` Will keep the modified changes in your working tree.

`git reset --hard HEAD^` **WILL THROW AWAY THE CHANGES YOU MADE !!!**

Comment: When I put: git reset --soft HEAD^ Git says me More? What it means?

Comment: @FernandoPie Did you find the ans?

Comment: I can't remember budy, but what iss the problem?

Comment: That's probably because your CLI interprets the "^" differently. Perhaps try put "HEAD^" in quotes?

Answer (score 398):

To keep the changes from the commit you want to undo

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

To destroy the changes from the commit you want to undo

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

You can also say

```
git reset --soft HEAD~2
```

to go back 2 commits.

Edit: As charsi mentioned, if you are on Windows you will need to put HEAD or commit hash in quotes.

```
git reset --soft "HEAD^"
git reset --soft "asdf"
```

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD^
More?
More?
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD
': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'`

What the heck? Why does nothing ever just work in `git`? I hate it.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe you are probably on windows and need to do `git reset --soft "HEAD^"`

Comment: Great answer, what I do is create in ~/.gitconfig add [alias] uncommit = reset --soft HEAD^ .... Then I can just write git uncommit and it will soft reset last commit

Comment: Windows tip: if you're too lazy to type in the additional quotes you can also use HEAD~ (e.g. git reset --soft HEAD~) which is exactly the same as "HEAD^" :)

Answer (score 171):

If you want to revert the commit *WITHOUT* throwing away work, use the --soft flag instead of --hard

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

**Be careful !** `reset --hard` will remove your local (uncommitted) modifications, too.

```
git reset --hard HEAD^
```

note: if you're on windows you'll need to quote the HEAD^ so

```
git reset --hard "HEAD^"
```

Comment: You don't have to quote the carat with the Git bash from msysgit.

Comment: tried this and just lost days of work here. read below for the `soft` version that will retain your work locally.

Comment: Note that this not only undoes the act of committing, but also throws away your changes.

Comment: Just as a note for anyone who has made the mistake of running this when they didn't want to discard the changes, **your changes are not gone**, they have just been hidden. You can undo this operation using `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}` to go back to where you just were. (`HEAD@{1}` means roughly "the commit I was just at 1 change ago", in this case the commit that you told Git you wanted to get rid of. Type `git reflog` to see all the recent changes.)

Comment: This doesn't remove uncommited modifications, this removes the whole commit with all the changes...

Thankfully I could get my changes back using Soren's tip

Comment: @Fabis: Actually, to be precise it does both -- my previous comment was only correct in the right context. Truly uncommitted changes are permanently lost, but the changes in your most recent commit can be restored with the provided tip.

Comment: you can undo a commit using    `git reset --hard HEAD~1`

Comment: This is ambiguous, as whether the exact thing removes the changes or not. Should be explicitly given the command for keeping the local modifications as this is risky

Comment: `git reset --soft HEAD\^` if using `zsh`

Comment: git reset --soft HEAD^
this one works, basically it will uncommit your local files and keep the changes on local

Answer (score 44):

Just a note - if you're using ZSH and see the error

```
zsh: no matches found: HEAD^
```

You need to escape the `^`

```
git reset --soft HEAD\^
```

Answer (score 33):

**If you commit to the wrong branch**

While on the wrong branch:

1. `git log -2` gives you hashes of 2 last commits, let's say `$prev` and `$last`
2. `git checkout $prev` checkout correct commit
3. `git checkout -b new-feature-branch` creates a new branch for the feature
4. `git cherry-pick $last` patches a branch with your changes

Then you can follow one of the methods suggested above to remove your commit from the first branch.

Comment: Is it works if you pushed to origin?

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 20):

If you haven't pushed your changes yet use `git reset --soft [Hash for one commit]` to rollback to a specific commit. `--soft` tells git to keep the changes being rolled back (i.e., mark the files as modified). `--hard` tells git to delete the changes being rolled back.

Comment: I've just learned without ruining anything, that subsequent git reset --soft HEAD~ keeps rollin' back without an intervening commit. Fortunately, I push to a bare repository and recovered from that. Good to learn these things the non-destructive, recoverable way.

Answer (score 5):

Be careful with that.

But you can use the rebase command

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

A `vi` will open and all you have to do is delete the line with the commit. Also can read instructions that were shown in proper edition @ `vi`. A couple of things can be performed on this mode.

Comment: What is that in Be careful with that? Is it git reset? I would agree.

Comment: The rebase command. You can destroy the commit history with it.

Comment: This didn't remove the commit. It removed the changes. I wanted to remove just the commit so I could add the commit to another branch.