# Throw away local commits in Git

Tags: git

Due to some bad cherry-picking, my local Git repository is currently five commits ahead of the origin, and not in a good state. I want to get rid of all these commits and start over again.

Obviously, deleting my working directory and re-cloning would do it, but downloading everything from GitHub again seems like overkill, and not a good use of my time.

Maybe `git revert` is what I need, but I don't want to end up *10* commits ahead of the origin (or even six), even if it does get the code itself back to the right state. I just want to pretend the last half-hour never happened.

Is there a simple command that will do this? It seems like an obvious use case, but I'm not finding any examples of it.

---

Note that this question is specifically about *commits*, *not* about:

- untracked files
- unstaged changes
- staged, but uncommitted changes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Various ways to remove local Git changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22620393/various-ways-to-remove-local-git-changes)

Answer (score 3777, accepted):

If your excess commits are only visible to you, you can just do 
`git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>` 
to move back to where the origin is. This will reset the state of the repository to the previous commit, and it will discard all local changes.

Doing a `git revert` makes *new* commits to remove *old* commits in a way that keeps everyone's history sane.

Comment: `git reset --hard <commit hash, branch, or tag>` if you want to go to a specific reference other than a remote branch.

Comment: This will not only discard local commits, but also throw away everything in your work tree (ie. you local files). If all you want to do is uncommit, but leave your work intact, you should do "git reset HEAD^" ... per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845731/how-to-uncommit-my-last-commit-in-git

Comment: git reset --soft origin/<branch-name> if you dont want to loose changes. as in case of --hard

Comment: If there are local tags this won't get rid of those. I noticed this when a Maven release failed due to duplicate tag.

Comment: You may want to do a Fetch after this. This fixed the number-of-commits-waiting-to-be-pushed counter on SourceTree.

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>` It will reset the project configuration as well, so take care of this. I have a big `.cfg` file which was reset to default. I had to spend hours on that again.

Comment: It's worth noting that this doesn't work if there is no remote for the branch/tracking branch. In that case you should utilize the commit hash solution that Sam Soffes mentions.

Comment: Please update your answer to include that this will actually delete all the work you did also (like @aaronbauman mentioned back in 2016). I just lost a lot of work when all I wanted was to undo my last commit, without using `revert`, so that I could take out a sensitive value before pushing.

Comment: @Ben Jackson: "This will reset the state of the repository" Do you mean the state of the repository or the current branch? Surely only the current branch is affected?

Comment: You have saved me a lot of time. How wonderful.

Comment: `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>` is very **danger**, it will.remove all your works which is not staged yet, but it don't cancel the resent commit. Delete the most recent commit, without destroying the work you've done, `git reset --soft HEAD~1` should be use, and it's save, **it just cancel your resent commit and will not delete any works you've done at your local, that's what we need to do for a wrong local commit.**

Answer (score 621):

Delete the most recent commit, without destroying the work you've done:

`git reset --soft HEAD~1`

Delete the most recent commit and remove changes:

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

Comment: Useful answer. Thank you!
I used git reset --soft origin/master

Comment: @TarunKumar THANK YOU!  I am using VS integration, and your solution was the only way I was able to wipe out a bunch of merge commits that I didn't want in a branch I didn't have permission to check in.

Comment: Thanks, just what I was looking for, "git reset --soft HEAD~1" did the work as I committed unintentionally and wanted to revert but had other files that I didn't want to be destroyed after revert.

Comment: in Windows `--hard "HEAD@{1}"`

Comment: last warning :  `--hard` will **destroy un-commit local changes**

Comment: This answer was particularly useful, as I want to discard the last local commit without knowing its SHA1 hash.

Comment: Having the --soft answer come first in the answer above might help some overzealous StackExchange skimmers... nothing lost, no knowledge gained

Comment: To me, this is the most useful answer, as I didn't want to get rid of changes, just a commit roll-back as I had mistakenly committed some large files. Also, worth noting, you can try doing a `git log` or `git status` before running the soft command to keep track of the current "HEAD".

Comment: @yurenchen I'm using windows  and don't have to use special commands or formatting. Perhaps it's your particular application or environment?

Answer (score 400):

Simply delete your local master branch and recreate it like so:

```
git branch -D master
git checkout origin/master -b master
```

Comment: This works well when backtracking your changes would cost too much time, which happened to me after a couple of rebases.

Comment: Useful for subtree pull/push problems among team members!

Comment: This is perfect when you want to restore a branch instead of just master.

Comment: Using egit in eclipse and this solution works perfect and its simple!

Comment: this is not a good way to delete single local commit. Better to use `git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>`

Comment: @Gabox if your solution is big, you have a bigger problem than deleting and checking out the branch :)

Comment: Maybe that solution will work, but that doesn't mean it's the proper one.

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. I had to checkout another branch to be able to delete the master

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me, the other answers didn't work! I had  pushed a change to remote, then I mistakenly thought I had pushed to the wrong branch - so I did a git revert on my local. But then i realized it was the correct branch after all, so i was stuck with an extra commit on local that even movign back a commit would still tell me my branch was 1 commit ahead.

Answer (score 266):

Try:

```
git reset --hard <the sha1 hash>
```

to reset your head to wherever you want to be. Use gitk to see which commit you want to be at. You can do reset within gitk as well.

Comment: Upvoted this b/c it's useful information, but Ben Jackson's answer gets the checkmark for exactly solving what I wanted -- in a way that didn't require me to look up commit hashes. :)

Comment: This is the one when your new branch has never been pushed to origin yet

Answer (score 84):

On your branch attempt:

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

Validate the reversal (to the state, with no local commits), using "`git log`" or "`git status`" hence.

Comment: @Troyseph :all the answers listed above, I attempted as it is, and did not get the scenario fixed. The generic approach, which was not illustrated in any of the above answers, is what has been tried to answered here.

Comment: The accepted answer is the same as yours, minus the generic branch name, and in the comments @Zoltan explicitly says `Just to be clear, if you're not working on master but on another branch, you should run git reset --hard origin/<your-branch-name>`

Answer (score 55):

## TL;DR

on your branch

`git reset --hard HEAD^` will throw away the last `1` local commit

`git reset --hard HEAD~n` will throw away the last `n` local commits

Answer (score 54):

If you are using **Atlassian SourceTree** app, you could use the reset option in the context menu.

[image]

Answer (score 53):

Simple Solution will be to match local master branch HEAD to origin/master branch HEAD

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

PS: origin/master - is remote pointer to master branch.
You can replace master with any branch name

Answer (score 46):

You can use this git command

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  I omitted the "/<branch_name>" since the branch I wanted to reset was my current branch.

Answer (score 35):

`git reset --hard @{u}`* deletes all your local changes on the current branch, including commits. I'm surprised no one has posted this yet considering you won't have to look up what commit to revert to or play with branches.

<sub>* That is, reset to the current branch at `@{upstream}`—commonly `origin/<branchname>`, but not always</sub>

Comment: Some shells like fish will interpret the "@" so you may have to put the '@{u}' in quotes, e.g. `git reset --hard '@{u}'. Anyway, good find!

Comment: How do you print the value of @{u}?

Comment: @PhilipRego `git name-rev @{u}` does the job if you're unsure of how current branch is configured for the push. Or maybe `git config -l | grep branch.$(git name-rev --name-only HEAD)` to more toroughly check the branch's config.

Answer (score 29):

Before answering let's add some background, explaining what is this `HEAD`. since some of the options below will result in detached head

## ***`First of all what is HEAD?`***

`HEAD` is simply a reference to the current commit (latest) on the current branch.
There can only be a single `HEAD` at any given time. (excluding `git worktree`)

The content of `HEAD` is stored inside `.git/HEAD` and it contains the 40 bytes SHA-1 of the current commit.

---

## ***`detached HEAD`***

If you are not on the latest commit - meaning that `HEAD` is pointing to a prior commit in history its called ***`detached HEAD`***.

[image]

On the command line, it will look like this- SHA-1 instead of the branch name since the `HEAD` is not pointing to the tip of the current branch

[image]

### [image]

#### A few options on how to recover from a detached HEAD:

---

#### [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout)

```
git checkout <commit_id>
git checkout -b <new branch> <commit_id>
git checkout HEAD~X // x is the number of commits t go back
```

This will checkout new branch pointing to the desired commit.
This command will checkout to a given commit.
At this point, you can create a branch and start to work from this point on.

```
# Checkout a given commit. 
# Doing so will result in a `detached HEAD` which mean that the `HEAD`
# is not pointing to the latest so you will need to checkout branch
# in order to be able to update the code.
git checkout <commit-id>

# create a new branch forked to the given commit
git checkout -b <branch name>
```

---

#### [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)

You can always use the `reflog` as well.
`git reflog` will display any change which updated the `HEAD` and checking out the desired reflog entry will set the `HEAD` back to this commit.

**Every time the HEAD is modified there will be a new entry in the `reflog`**

```
git reflog
git checkout HEAD@{...}
```

This will get you back to your desired commit

[image]

---

#### ***[`git reset --hard <commit_id>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)***

"Move" your HEAD back to the desired commit.

```sh
# This will destroy any local modifications.
# Don't do it if you have uncommitted work you want to keep.
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32

# Alternatively, if there's work to keep:
git stash
git reset --hard 0d1d7fc32
git stash pop
# This saves the modifications, then reapplies that patch after resetting.
# You could get merge conflicts if you've modified things which were
# changed since the commit you reset to.
```

- Note: ([Since Git 2.7](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.7.0.txt))
  you can also use the `git rebase --no-autostash` as well.

---

#### ***[`git revert <sha-1>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)***

"Undo" the given commit or commit range.
The reset command will "undo" any changes made in the given commit.
A new commit with the undo patch will be committed while the original commit will remain in the history as well.

```sh
# add new commit with the undo of the original one.
# the <sha-1> can be any commit(s) or commit range
git revert <sha-1>
```

---

This schema illustrates which command does what.
As you can see there `reset && checkout` modify the `HEAD`.

[image]

Answer (score 18):

Remove untracked files (uncommitted local changes)

```
git clean -df
```

Permanently deleting all local commits and get latest remote commit

```
git reset --hard origin/<branch_name>
```

Answer (score 18):

Use any number of times, to revert back to the last commit without deleting any files that you have recently created.

```
git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

Then use

```
git reset HEAD <name-of-file/files*>
```

to unstage, or untrack.

Answer (score 17):

I had a situation where I wanted to remove a commit that wasn't pushed, but the commit was before another one. To do so, I've used the following command

`git rebase -i HEAD~2` -> it will rebase the last two commits

And I used 'drop' for the commit signature that I wanted to remove.

Answer (score 15):

To see/get the SHA-1 id of the commit you want to come back too

```
gitk --all
```

To roll back to that commit

```
git reset --hard sha1_id
```

!Note. All the commits that were made after that commit will be deleted (and all your modification to the project). So first better clone the project to another branch or copy to another directory.

Comment: this is great for situations where the remote is no longer available, and one simply needs to reset to some local commit.  gitk is awesome - was not aware of it beforehand.

Comment: If you're already in gitk you could as well simply right-click on the commit and select "reset branch XY to here".

Comment: And the newer commits won't immediately be deleted. There's just no branch pointing to them anymore (remember, a branch is nothing but a "bookmark" to a particular commit).

Answer (score 15):

If 
Your branch is ahead of '`origin/XXX`' by 5 commits.

You can issue:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~5
```

And it should remove the last 5 commits.

Answer (score 11):

For local commits which are not being pushed, you can also use `git rebase -i` to delete or squash a commit.

Comment: I know this may not be the shortest solution, but I upvoted you since IMHO `git rebase -i` is a more generic way to solve many similar problems and can be helpful in a variety of situations.

Comment: Use the `drop` keyword (instead of deleting a line) when removing all commits to avoid having the rebase aborted.

Answer (score 6):

For those interested in the Visual Studio solution, here is the drill:

1. In the `Team Explorer` window, connect to the target repo.
2. Then from `Branches`, right-click the branch of interest and select `View history`.
3. Right-click a commit in the `History` window and choose `Reset -> Delete changes (--hard)`.

That will throw away your local commits and reset the state of your repo to the selected commit. I.e. the changes after you pulled the repo will be lost.

**UPDATE**

The above procedure works fine up until VS2019; in VS2022 there is the New Git Experience. The workflow is similar but the UI is a bit different. Instead of `Team Explorer`, use `Manage Branches` from the `Git` menu. Now just click a branch on the left and its history is displayed on the right. Then go `Right Click -> Reset -> Delete Changes (--hard)`

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to throw away local commits and keep the modifications done in files then do
**git reset @~**
Other answers addressed the hard reset

Answer (score 5):

Find the sha1 for the commit you want to revert to:

```
za$ git reflog
... snip ...
cf42fa2... HEAD@{0}: commit: fixed misc bugs
~
~
cf42fa2... HEAD@{84}: commit: fixed params for .....
73b9363... HEAD@{85}: commit: Don't symlink to themes on deployment.
547cc1b... HEAD@{86}: commit: Deploy to effectif.com web server.
1dc3298... HEAD@{87}: commit: Updated the theme.
18c3f51... HEAD@{88}: commit: Verify with Google webmaster tools.
26fbb9c... HEAD@{89}: checkout: moving to effectif
```

And then use --mixed flag so that you "reset HEAD and index":

```
za$ git reset --mixed cf42fa2
```

Available flags:

```
za$ git reset -h

-q, --quiet           be quiet, only report errors
--mixed               reset HEAD and index
--soft                reset only HEAD
--hard                reset HEAD, index and working tree
--merge               reset HEAD, index and working tree
--keep                reset HEAD but keep local changes
--recurse-submodules[=<reset>]
                      control recursive updating of submodules
-p, --patch           select hunks interactively
-N, --intent-to-add
```

Answer (score 4):

```
git reset --hard <SHA-Code>
```

This will come in handy if you have made some mistakes on your local copy that you want to make sure doesn't get pushed to your remote branch by mistake.

The SHA-Code can be obtained by looking at webVersion of your git dashboard for the last commit on the branch.

This way you can get synchronized with the last commit on the branch.

You can do `git pull` after you have successfully completed the hard reset to confirm nothing new to syn i.e. you get to see the message.

Your branch is up to date with `Origin/<Branch Name>`

Answer (score 1):

Updated:

You can use new GIT LFS here: https://git-lfs.github.com/

```
git lfs migrate import --include="*.file_type"
```

then git push

Answer (score 1):

You could look at using an interactive rebase with the drop command

So for say the last three commits...

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Swap out the pick commands

```
pick <hash1> Commit message 1
pick <hash2> Commit message 2
pick <hash3> Commit message 3
```

for drop commands

```
drop <hash1> Commit message 1
drop <hash2> Commit message 2
drop <hash3> Commit message 3
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get your local repo into a complete mess, then a reliable way to throw away local commits in Git is to...

1. Use "git config --get remote.origin.url" to get URL of remote origin
2. Rename local git folder to "my_broken_local_repo"
3. Use "git clone <url_from_1>" to get fresh local copy of remote git repository

In my experience Eclipse handles the world changing around it quite well.  However, you may need to select affected projects in Eclipse and clean them to force Eclipse to rebuild them.  I guess other IDEs may need a forced rebuild too.

A side benefit of the above procedure is that you will find out if your project relies on local files that were not put into git.  If you find you are missing files then you can copy them in from "my_broken_local_repo" and add them to git.  Once you have confidence that your new local repo has everything you need then you can delete "my_broken_local_repo".

Answer (score 0):

For all unstaged changes `git checkout -- .`

for specific file `git checkout -- path/to/file/to/revert`

Answer (score 0):

I actually learned that if you've ran the code before hard committing (*hard resetting), you can reach to it by "Target" folder in your IDE or the project folder and do whatever you want with it.. I saw it a few minutes ago while re-writing my things I apparently lost with "hard" reset, deleted the "bin" folder since I didn't need it anymore as I would have rewrote by that time which made my commits sane rather than lots of new stuff appearing as if I just added them, the things I made new changes to only appeared.
If you do this mistake, then I hope this information is useful for you guys.

Basically: Hard reset takes all the commit off GitHub and saves "probably" moves it to a folder "bin" in my project where I saw it on github's commit where the files came from as if I just added them, which happened in my case.

I regret it and I learned that "Soft" is for just pulling off GitHub and not Destroy the work (not delete the indexes from changes we did)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  
I have the feeling that the git terms are a bit mixed up in your answer. There's no "hard commit". Maybe hard reset?  
Although others already posted that method (~25 times). Make sure you read the [how to write good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help center, and make your answer technical term wise correct.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still trying and I seem to sound really... complicated to others since I keep going on with my terminology which is my mistake, but yes, basically when you run your project before hard resetting, I'm sure the previous one that was copied and ran by IDE still might be in the "Target" folder of your project which is used when you test your project or compile packages instead of affecting the current one, so it's like the carbon copy of your project and it takes a bit of extra space... you can maybe copy things you need from it.
Hope this is more cleaner!