# pull a branch that has amended changes, dropping local commits

Tags: git

How do I force to pull from a branch that has amended changes?

I get the error

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

I don't need the local branch, so I used to solve this by searching for the last clean commit, and then reset with

```
git reset --hard 27f35e56b4bb3467705e5afa7f7f24e5b3997140
git pull
```

Is there a way to just force taking the remote branch, dropping the local branch **with one command**?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
git reset --hard  origin/<branch_name>
```

source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36337438/1069083