# Nothing to commit, working tree clean after calling git checkout

Tags: git

I tried to delete my last commit. I thought that `git checkout` followed by the hash of the `commit` would replace my current code with the code of the `commit`. This didn't work and I get now a message which says `Nothing to commit, working tree clean`. How can I get rid of this message and delete my last commit?

Comment: `git checkout <commit-specifier>` is the front end command for *extracting* a commit into the staging-area and work-tree. Why would you expect this to *delete* a commit? (This is a real question, by the way—it seems likely that some bad advice led to the conclusion.) Commits can't exactly be deleted, but you can get the effect you want in some (many) cases using `git reset`.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-to-undo-the-most-recent-commits-in-git/#927386

Comment: @MadhuBhat I wanted to reset my code the the last commit which shouldn't be deleted with that

Comment: So do you only want to undo your local changes and not your last commit?

Comment: I thought that I can just continue where everything still worked, and then commit it

Comment: If you only want to remove all your local changes that haven't been committed yet, you need to use `git checkout .`

Comment: Note that it would remove only unstaged local changes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throw away local commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097456/throw-away-local-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doing `git checkout <hash>` you went into so called "detached head" state, which in simple terms means you're not on any branch right now. If you want to return to your normal branch just do:

`git checkout <branch name>`

(where `<branch name>` can be any of `master`, `develop`, `hotfix` - it really depends how you name them and what flow you use to manage your development/release cycle... try `git branch --list` to get a list).

After that, if you want to delete the last commit you can do:

`git reset --hard HEAD~1`

but be very careful about the `--hard` switch as **it will physically delete the most recent commit**, which basically means it's unrecoverable (and I don't really remember if manipulating the reflog would help restore it in this situation).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37269222/git-status-nothing-to-commit-working-directory-clean-however-wth-changes-com/37270273) for more details, but it sounds like the repo doesn't know about your local branch. You need to set your remote repo by using:

`git branch -u <upstream branch>`

so if you're trying to push to master branch, use

`git branch -u origin/master`