# conflict one file again and again when i take pull on dev server

Tags: git

When I git pull from our development server for a specific file, I get conflicted again and again even after removing that file from the development server. It will show the conflict in the next pull again. I did checkout that specific file but still it show conflict in next pull.

I have tried to delete this file but in next pull it shows the conflict for the same file. I don't want to keep the content just want to remove local changes and take the pull. How to resolve this conflict?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Throw away local commits in git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097456/throw-away-local-commits-in-git)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that master is the local branch you're replacing, and that "origin/master" is the remote branch you want to reset to:

```
 git reset --hard origin/master
```

This will remove all local changes and pull it again from remote master

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could just discard your local changes and do this

```
git fetch --all
git reset origin/master --hard
```

but why would you want to discard your local changes? Maybe you could just do

```
git pull
```

and then look for conflicted files, solve the conflicts - as described here [Resolving a merge conflict](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-a-merge-conflict-using-the-command-line/) - and then commit and push your changes.

```
git commit -m "Merged"
git push
```