# How to Uncommit Git Change

Tags: git

I'd like to un-commit changes against which I've run "git commit."

In particular, I'd like to specify the files.

Example:

```
> #5 commits ago 
> commit -m "bug fix" A.java
> 
> #bunch of commits occurred
> 
> [command to uncommit] A.java
```

**Note** I do not want to remove A.java from my repo. I just want to return it to its base state, i.e. when I had run `git clone repo`.

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: check this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845731/how-to-uncommit-my-last-commit-in-git

Comment: Please [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49130829/7178104) to check how to uncommit git change.

Answer (score 3):

Be careful with rebasing, if you have pushed your commit already you'll have to force push and will probably run into troubles unless you know what you are doing.

Use `git revert $SHAYOUWNATOREVERT` to revert the commit you don't want anymore. This will basically create an "inverted" commit that undoes the given one.

Comment: Then the interactive rebase is the way to go.

Comment: So when I run "git push origin," can I append a SHA to only push the SHA's that I'd like to push? Some of my git commit's should not be pushed to master.

Comment: If nothing has been pushed, I'd agree with @hvgotcodes' answer as well. I have been answering under the assumption that you both committed and pushed your changes. Rebase away if you haven't pushed yet.

Answer (score 2):

You can do a rebase interactive and remove the commit.  It might not work if later commits depend on that commit though.

`git rebase -i HEAD~5`

and just delete the appropriate line, then save and exit.

DO NOT do this if you have pushed to remote.

Answer (score 2):

Unless A.java contains private data that cannot exist in the repo history, you should commit a deletion of the file, not try to remove its previous existence.

```
git rm A.java
```

If the file contains sensitive data which must be removed, it is possible to remove the history of the file, but it will rewrite refs, require a forced push, and require extra work on the part of anyone who has cloned or pulled your current refs.

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data

In short:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch A.java' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Edit to incorporate answer if trying to restore a version from another repo or branch:

If A.java is a file that you've modified, and you wish to return it to the original version that is available at `upstream/master` then this will replace your current copy:

```
git checkout upstream/master A.java
```

Comment: I do not want to remove A.java from the git repo though. After cloning a repo, I then modified and committed A.java. Now, I'd like to undo those changes and revert/return A.java to its original, cloned version.

Comment: Assuming `upstream/master` contains the version you want, `git checkout upstream/master A.java` will get you the original version.

Comment: Can I just replace "upstream/master" with the https://... link to the repo that I cloned?

Comment: Not as far as I know. `git remote add upstream https://...` will make the checkout command work assuming master exists upstream and contains the version you want.

Comment: Can you please tell me what 'upstream master' means?

Comment: `upstream` is often used to refer to a repo you've forked from. It is often used as the remote name for a repository you've forked, but there's nothing that requires you to. You can replace `upstream` with anything you'd like in the `remote add` command. `master` is the branch name you want. It is often the default/primary branch. If you forked a different branch, you would want to continue to use that branch, not `master`. More on upstream/downstream: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739376/definition-of-downstream-and-upstream