# Facing issue in git auto merge abort

Tags: git, patch

I am using below command to apply the patch using 'git am --continue ' command. It doesn't executed successfully. I tried to abort the process using below command.

> git am --abort

But I am getting below error:

> **Resolve operation not in progress, we are not resuming.**

Pls suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: What does `git status` say?

Comment: git status doesn't show anything.. It shows 'nothing to commit working directory clean'

Comment: Then `git am --abort` won't work because there's nothing in progress. If there were, git would say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it shows 'nothing to commit working directory clean

Then check your history: `git log`, for a new commit created duringthe `git am` process.

- If there is none, you can try again to apply your patch.
- if there is, and its content is not to your liking, [you can throw it away](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2846154/6309) and retry your patch.