# git reset caused issues with pushing subsequent commits

Tags: git, github

I went to soft reset a commit because I accidentally added a large file instead of adding it to my .gitignore file. This file resulted in any attempt at `git push` to fail. I used `git reset --soft HEAD` for the particular commit causing an issue and tried to redo it. My understanding was that this would just restage my files, not remove any of them. (Followed suggestions from [How to uncommit my last commit in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2845731/how-to-uncommit-my-last-commit-in-git))

I now seem to have totally messed up my git and most of the changes from the other commits are gone.

[image]

The commit I wanted to reset was HEAD@{15}. Files that I wanted to push to my remote repo from HEAD@{14} through HEAD@{5} are no longer visible anywhere or available to push. Did I just lose all of those files or is there a way I can still push those changes to my online repo?

Honestly at this point I'd be fine undoing these commits as long as all of the files from these commits are returned to my local repository. Then I could just restage and recommit accordingly.

Comment: This the problem with `reset`: it means too many things. You should confine your use of `reset` to mean "repoint this branch name at this commit". If what you meant was something else, you should have given a command that meant that. Perhaps you meant `git restore`, for example. Or `git revert`. — Anyway, it would help if you told us which commit in that list is the problem, and what you _actually said to Git_.

Comment: @matt as I said, I was following advice from a different post but was apparently misguided in the use of ```reset``` as that was not my understanding. Anyways, the commit HEAD@{15} was the problem and was the commit I wanted to reset. I used ```git reset --soft HEAD@{15}``` thinking I would have the files from that commit restaged so I could change the commit. However, they were not.

Comment: So, as I said, that means "make main point at HEAD@{15}". To undo what you did, just do it again: say `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}`. That won't solve whatever you wanted to solve, but you will be right back where you were when you said the thing you said.

Comment: Also I do not really know what "restage" means, so I am ignoring that every time you say it. Sorry about that.

Comment: If you are worried about losing files from `HEAD@{5}` you could just create another branch there or what?