# Reverting to a specific commit based on commit id with Git?

Tags: git

With `git log`, I get a list of commits that I have made so far.

```
commit f5c5cac0033439c17ebf905d4391dc0705dbd5f1
Author: prosseek 
Date:   Fri Sep 3 14:36:59 2010 -0500

    Added and modified the files.

commit c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07
Author: prosseek 
Date:   Tue Aug 31 08:59:32 2010 -0500

    Just simple test for core.editor.

... etc ...
```

- How can I revert it back to a specific commit? For example, what should I do if I want to go back to `commit c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07`?
- Is there any other/better way to go back to a specific commit with Git? For example, can I put some label of each commit to get it back with the label?

Comment: Even though this question is actually older than the one it's now marked as a duplicate of, that one has a better answer. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147643/should-i-vote-to-close-a-duplicate-question-even-though-its-much-newer-and-ha/147651#147651

Comment: This is a perfect example of how f--k'd up git is (from bwawok's answer): *"... then if you wanted to push this to someone else who has the new history, it would fail"*. What good is it if you can't check it back into the remote repository??? I am absolutely amazed at how difficult Git has made simple operations.

Comment: @jww I literally have been reading for an hour now on how to go back to a previous commit and I still don't know the answer. You are absolutely correct, git makes things more complicated than it should be.

Comment: @robben Reset then force push

Answer (score 860, accepted):

Do you want to roll back your repo to that state, or you just want your local repo to look like that?

If you `reset --hard`, it will make your local code and local history be just like it was at that commit. But if you wanted to push this to someone else who has the new history, it would fail:

```
git reset --hard c14809fa
```

And if you `reset --soft`, it will move your HEAD to where they were , but leave your local files etc. the same:

```
git reset --soft c14809fa
```

So what exactly do you want to do with this reset?

Edit -

You can add "tags" to your repo.. and then go back to a tag. But a tag is really just a shortcut to the sha1.

You can tag this as TAG1.. then a `git reset --soft c14809fa`, `git reset --soft TAG1`, or `git reset --soft c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07` would all do the same thing.

Comment: I needed to roll back to that state. But it's good to know that I may have the option of 'look like that'.  Thanks for letting me know. BTW, what option is the default? hard or soft?

Comment: @prosseek the default is actually mixed. 
--mixed
Resets the index but not the working tree (i.e., the changed files are preserved but not marked for commit) and reports what has not been updated. This is the default action.
 See http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Comment: @prosseek: If the various modes of reset are a bit confusing to you, even after reading the man page (carefully!) you could try this other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-to-me-git-reset-in-plain-english

Comment: Peter's answer below makes more sense than this

Comment: git reset --hard c14809fa ( note: and not necessary to again do git pull )

Comment: To clarify: "git reset --soft" does NOT leave the history the same, as it removes all the commit entries done after the one reset to and labels the files from those newer commits as "Changes to be committed". I guess it depends on how you define "history". The sentence "but leave your history etc. the same." made me interpret this answer as if the command doesn't affect any of the commits at all, which it does. See Peter A's answer on how to keep the commits done after the commit reverted to.

Comment: "at that commit" is ambiguous:

if I do "git reset --hard X" is the repo state same as before commit X or after commit X ...

Comment: Do not use soft or hard reset if you just want to have a look at your older commit, use  Peter suggestion! For example:
git checkout c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07

Comment: This worked, but then I needed "git push --force" in place of my normal "git push".

Comment: @bwawok , why put a " c14809fa" and not the full hash? What is the min. no.of characters to include of the hash? will it work as long as it's different?

Comment: Live + Time saver.

Comment: Post that we need to take a pull

Answer (score 240):

I think, bwawok's answer is wrong at some point:

> if you do
>
> ```
> git reset --soft c14809fa
> ```
>
> It will make your local files changed to be like they were then, but leave your history etc. the same.

According to [manual: git-reset](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html), "git reset --soft"...

> does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets the head to <commit>, just like all modes do). This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git status would put it.

So it will "remove" newer commits from the branch. This means, after looking at your old code, you cannot go to the newest commit in this branch again, easily. So it does the opposide as described by bwawok: Local files are not changed (they look exactly as before "git reset --soft"), but the history is modified (branch is truncated after the specified commit).

The command for bwawok's answer might be:

```
git checkout <commit>
```

You can use this to peek at old revision: How did my code look yesterday?

(I know, I should put this in comments to this answer, but stackoverflow does not allow me to do so! My reputation is too low.)

Comment: but `git checkout` is read only, therefore you can't commit an old revision.

Comment: @Peter A: After "git reset --soft" followed by "git checkout", I don't see a change to a file I've been working on. Could it be because I'm not in the master branch?

Comment: Also you can then do 'git checkout <YOUR_BRANCH>' to come to the original state after viewing different commits.

Answer (score 53):

`git reset c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07` is what you're after...

Comment: Won't have to type the entire sha, just a little bit will work

Comment: @bwawok: But it's faster to select and middle-click-paste than to type even an abbreviated SHA1!

Comment: Will a `git push origin mybranch` then cause the origin repo to be reverted?

Comment: @javadba Not without a '--force' if there is a deviation 'off of' a previous ancestor.

Comment: git hard reset "enter commit id here" : It will roll back to you till that stage

Answer (score 29):

If you want to force the issue, you can do:

```
git reset --hard c14809fafb08b9e96ff2879999ba8c807d10fb07
```

send you back to how your git clone looked like at the time of the checkin

Comment: in what cases would you need to force?

Comment: what does "at the time of the checkin" mean? ambiguous.

if I do "git reset --hard X" is the repo state same as before commit X or after commit X ...

Comment: git reset --hard X. This will roll back the repository state as before commit X. It will make your local code and local history be just like it was at that commit. But then if you wanted to push this to local master or remote master with different history, it would fail. So it will be read only version of your repository.

Comment: You would want to force the issue if say you checkout a remote branch that you have never checked out before and when you do a `git pull` it forces you to do a merge when all you want is the code sitting at HEAD for that branch.