# How to undo commits in git

Tags: git, version-control, git-commit

I have committed twice and have not pushed yet. How can I undo this like though I didn't do anything. I had always thought that this would reset it:

```
git checkout master
```

but that didn't work. I also googled and found this post: [Delete commits from a branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/how-can-i-delete-a-git-commit)

The post says that I can do

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

However, when I do a git status it's still saying I'm behind by 2 commits

Comment: I looked at that as I said in my post!

Comment: Indeed, but I don't think you read the answer properly...

Comment: See also [How do you roll back (reset) a git repository to a particular commit?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1616957/456814), [Reverting to a specific commit based on commit id with git?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3639115/456814), and [Revert to a commit by SHA hash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1895059/456814).

Comment: see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338728/delete-commits-from-a-branch-in-git/23967514#23967514

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git reset --hard HEAD` will reset it to your `HEAD`.

To go 2 commits back use:

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to go back to what's in the remote repo, you can do:

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

If you want to reset back to a particular local commit, just tell it the hash instead:

```
git reset --hard <hash of commit>
```

You might also first do a `git fetch` to make sure you know about any changes in the remote repo.