# pulling specific commit to local development environment

Tags: git, bitbucket

Tried to google this back and forth, without luck.

Hello.
I have 2 environments: local and production.

Right now I want to get the commit I have made from production environment and pull it into the development environment.

I cannot see the commit I have made in the commit list. I know I have pushed it to master branch, and I don't see it there.So I would like to know where can I see it?

Also, how can I pull this specific commit to my development environment?

Comment: Did you commit AND push? Or just commit?

Comment: I did used this to push, and it returned it did pushed it.
`git push -f origin master`

Comment: If you pushed to your remote repository and it's not showing up there, then the push didn't succeed.

Comment: As for pulling a specific commit, you already have the commit history if you cloned and fetched recently. This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639115/reverting-to-a-specific-commit-based-on-commit-id-with-git

Comment: @mariocatch thanks for that. Any idea why the push did not succeeded? it does return it pushed successfully: