# Undo pushed changes to a file

Tags: git, git-reset, git-revert

I recently pushed a commit of changes of a project in a remote repository.
I just figured out that one of the files that I usually don't commit its changes because it could contain sensitive information was included.

I want to undo the committed changes to that file (to the last previous state) without losing the changes of the commit in the other files.

From this:

- Change FileSensitive -- ++
- Change File1
- Change File2
- New File3
- New File4

To this:

- Change File1
- Change File2
- New File3
- New File4

For the moment, only I have access to that repository, so there's no problem for rewriting history, so when I give access to that remote repository they won't see that sensitive info in history. So, how can I do that?

Comment: You can rebase your repo to the previous commit id..just follow this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639115/reverting-to-a-specific-commit-based-on-commit-id-with-git

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 7):

1. `git reset --soft HEAD^` to undo the last commit keeping all changes made by the last commit in the index.
2. `git checkout HEAD <path to FileSensitive>` to unstage and discard the change on FileSensitive. (Note the change on FileSensitive is lost by this command.)
3. `git commit` and `git push -f` to update the remote repo.