# How To Install and Use git-sizer for Windows (Github, VS Code)

Tags: go, github

I have a really large project I want to upload. I am the author of below question.

[Git Push remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67086183/git-push-remote-fatal-pack-exceeds-maximum-allowed-size/)

So following this person's guidance, I want to install git-sizer on my repository and use it.

https://github.com/github/git-sizer

Here are the steps I took so far:

1. Installed golang on Windows using the installer
   https://golang.org/doc/install
2. Followed instructions on github page and put in windows cmd:

   **go get github.com/github/git-sizer**
3. This downloaded a bin folder and pkg folder to my directory. In the bin folder I see git-sizer.exe
4. Now the instructions on Github say "Either add $GOPATH/bin to your PATH, or copy the executable file (git-sizer or git-sizer.exe) to a directory that is already in your PATH."

I apologize, but what does this mean??? I want to use git-sizer on Visual Studio Code. I tried google searching and also searching on YouTube how to use this. I have git-bash installed on Visual Studio Code.

I'm utterly confused and feel helpless. My English is fine, but I don't understand these instructions. Maybe it's because I don't know Go or because I'm weak in this area.

Could someone please tell me what to do in order to use this tool on Windows + VS Code with git bash installed? In a simple manner that I can follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not need to use Go in order to benefit from git-sizer

As stated in "[Getting Started](https://github.com/github/git-sizer#getting-started)"

- Go to the [releases page](https://github.com/github/git-sizer/releases) and download the ZIP file corresponding to your platform. (for example: [`git-sizer-1.3.0-windows-amd64.zip`](https://github.com/github/git-sizer/releases/download/v1.3.0/git-sizer-1.3.0-windows-amd64.zip))
- Unzip the file.
- Move the executable file (git-sizer or git-sizer.exe) into your PATH.

That way, no need to build from source. You can start using it right away.

Comment: I apologize. What is my PATH? And how do I use it or start using it? :D Let's say my project that I'm uploading to github is in a folder named presta. Is that my path?

Comment: @d7l2k4 type (assuming Linux/Mac) `echo $PATH` to see where your OS will look for an executable. You can put your executable in a folder that you add to your PATH: https://askubuntu.com/a/322773/5470. On Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65640893/6309. On Mac: https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/.