# Git Revert, Checkout and Reset for Dummies

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset, git-revert

Sorry, but this trio of git commands is taxing my intelligence.

Is it possible to set up a group wiki for total newbies to cover these three git commands? What I am trying to learn is how to restore or rollback files and projects to a prior state.

As I have no experience with subversion or other centralized version control software, reference to how they did things differently is unnecessary and often confusing.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a ton of documentation and tutorials out there. What have you read that didn't work for you?

Comment: I have read the relevant section of the git scm community book, as well as Pro-Git and have purchased the Peepcode screencast as well as the Peepcode PDF. I also have Swicegoods Pragmatic Guide to Git. I also just bought Loeliger's Version Control with Git, but have yet to read that book.

Comment: related question (for git-reset): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english/2530073#2530073

Comment: @haziz: Have you read the manpages? Have you read (and understood) all of the community book and ProGit up until the "relevant section"? (It's hard to imagine all of these would be completely covered in a single section...) These are separate questions, and if you don't understand the documentation you've read, it sounds like you need to back up and read the basics. You could always try the Git parable... http://tom.preston-werner.com/2009/05/19/the-git-parable.html

Comment: @haziz - as written, this question is unanswerable. As *Andrew Marshall* said, show what did and didn't work for you. In other words, write a question that contains specific steps of creating one or more files/branches/whatever, and show the steps that you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the resources you mentioned are quite popular, and I'm surprised you didn't find them helpful. The man pages for each of those commands are probably the most *descriptive* resource, but are admittedly dry and dense. Here is a brief summary of the difference between the three commands:

- `git revert` takes a treeish and creates a new commit undoing the changes made in the given commit
- `git checkout` does just that: checks out a treeish. If you pass a branch name, you'll move to the `HEAD` of that branch, if you pass a non-`HEAD` commit or tag, you'll enter a "detached `HEAD`" state. Regardless, your working tree will now be the same as it was at the commit (there are some edge cases here with untracked/new files).
- `git reset` takes a treeish, and erases all the commits up to (but not including) the given commit, but without altering the current state of any of the files. That is, the commits are gone, but your working tree remains in the same state. Passing `--hard` also puts the files back to the state.

(Yes, [a treeish is a real thing](http://book.git-scm.com/4_git_treeishes.html))

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link may be helpful.
http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html

Comment: And you also can refer to [http://progit.org/book](http://progit.org/book), and you'll find more docs in [http://git-scm.com/documentation](http://git-scm.com/documentation).

Comment: I have read the relevant section (quite brief) in the git-scm community book as well as some of Pro-Git. I am not kidding when I say this is taxing my intelligence.

Comment: Hi @haziz I suggest you build a new project and test the commands' difference. ;)

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to set up a group wiki for total newbies to cover these three git commands?

Honestly? Probably, yeah. Definitely, maybe. I've never set up a wiki, though, so I don't know if I'd be able to help you. :P

In all seriousness, though, this link might help you if you haven't seen it before: http://wiki.freegeek.org/index.php/Git_for_dummies

Additionally, check out this question if you haven't parsed it already: [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](https://stackoverflow.com/q/315911/677526)

Answer (score 0):

http://progit.org/2011/07/11/reset.html helped me a lot in seeing the similarities and differences between checkout and reset. Revert is a different story that creates a new commit, canceling out another.