# Symfony2: How to update a bundle whose source files have been modified?

Tags: symfony, bundles

I am using the KNP Pagination Bundle. I customized the twig file in the bundle source. Then I found a better way of doing it without touching the bundle's files.

Unfortunately, now everytime that I do

```
bin/vendors install
```

I get the following error:-

> "KNP Paginator Bundle" has local modifications. Please revert or commit/push before running this command again.

My .gitignore file has ignored /vendors

And my deps file has the bundle included too.

Is there a way to uninstall a bundle? So that I can reinstall it?
Or what is the best way to solve my problem?

Comment: Note that if you want to modify a bundle's views you can either create a ```app/Resources/KnpUserBundle/views/``` and put the files there, or you can create a [child bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/inheritance.html).

Answer (score 11):

`./bin/vendors` doesn't care about content of `.gitignore`. You can fork desired bundle, do your changes there and change `deps` file to point to your fork instead.

If you still want to use original bundle and just reinstall it, you can either run `./bin/vendors install --reinstall` or just delete the bundle folder from `vendor` directory and run `./bin/vendors install` again.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know there was a --reinstall option.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `git --reset`? The vendors are fetched using git clone after all.

[Can you explain what "git reset" does in plain english?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english)