# git rebase basics

Tags: git, git-rebase

I have started using `git rebase` recently and am not 100% certain I'm doing it right. For the sake of the question, there are two branches in origin, `master` and `next`, which was branched from `master`.

Since last sync between the two, `master` had 2 commits and `next` 6:

```
$ git log --oneline origin/next..origin/master
59b5552 master commit #2
485a811 master commit #1

$ git log --oneline origin/master..origin/next
4ebf401 next commit #6
e9b6586 next commit #5
197ada0 next commit #4
4a2c3c6 next commit #3
040a055 next commit #2
84537bf next commit #1
```

When I checkout `next` and execute `git rebase -i origin/master`, I get the following:

```
$ git status
# On branch next
# Your branch and 'origin/next' have diverged,
# and have 8 and 6 different commits each, respectively.
```

And finally after doing `git pull --rebase`, the two commits from `master` are in `next`:

```
$ git log --oneline origin/next..next 
8741d09 master commit #2
485a811 master commit #1
```

Questions:

1. Is this correct approach?
2. Why are there `8 and 6` different commits until `pull --rebase` is run?
3. Is it possible to simplify the flow?

Much obliged :)

Answer (score 102, accepted):

Let's start from the beginning. Here's a diagram of your original state:

```
A-B-C  (master, origin/master)
 \
  D-E-F-G-H-I  (next, origin/next)
```

When you checked out `next` and rebased `next` onto `origin/master`, it created 6 new commits after the two that are already on `origin/master`. These new commits have "master commit #2" (`C` in my diagram) as their ancestor, not their original ancestor where `origin/master` and `origin/next` diverged (`A` in my diagram), so their hashes will be different. I believe this is why you'll see that `next` has 8 different commits from `origin/next`: the 2 from `origin/master` and the 6 "rehashed" commits that were on `origin/next`.

After `git checkout next ; git rebase -i origin/master`, you should have this:

```
A-B-C  (master, origin/master)
 \   \
  \   D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I' (next)
   \
    D-E-F-G-H-I  (origin/next)
```

You can see that `next` does have 8 commits that aren't on `origin/next`, and `origin/next` does have 6 commits that aren't on `next`. Granted this is just according to the SHA-1 hashes of the commits. The actual content should match very closely if you `git diff origin/next next` -- the diff should just show the changes from `B` and `C` (as labeled in the diagram).

When you do `git pull --rebase` while still on `next`, it fetches changes from the source (the remote `origin/next`) and rebases the current branch (`next`) onto that remote. This causes the changes that were in the `next` but *not* in `origin/next` to appear after `origin/next` on the new `next` branch. It should look like this:

```
A-B-C  (master, origin/master)
 \
  D-E-F-G-H-I  (origin/next)
             \
              B'-C' (next)
```

If this is what you wanted the history graph to look like, then you've succeeded.

However, I suspect you really wanted things to look like the middle diagram, especially if `next` is a feature branch where you're working on the next piece of the project and `master` is for stable code and small bug fixes. If so, then you should have done `git push` instead of `git pull --rebase` to make the remote reflect your version of history instead of the other way around.

Comment: I assume `git rebase --pull` is much like `git pull --rebase`.  It does a fetch and then a `git rebase @{u}`  Well, that's a lie, but it is an easy way to think about it.  But the point is that your local branch is reset to @{u} and then all local commits on your old branch before the reset are replayed on top of what upstream has.  This allows a trivial fastforward push upstream.

Comment: Assuming `git rebase --pull` was a typo and should have been `git pull --rebase`, then I think that would reorder `next` into `D'-E'-F'-G'-H'-I'-B'-C'`. Does that sound right? If so, I'll edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: After `git pull --rebase` you will get A-D-E-F-G-H-I-B'-C'.  The g-p-r will always force your local branch (next) to contain all of the commits on @{u} (origin/next) and then anything which is unique to next will be replayed (probably cherry-picked) on top.  Congratulate git for being smart enough to not attempt to create D"-E"-F"-G"-H"-I"

Comment: Really sorry for the typo, it should be `git pull --rebase`. Thank you for the explanation, I now understand what happens. Is the flow I'm doing correct? `git rebase` and then `git pull --rebase` or is there some other way?

Comment: @DavidKuridža: There is no particular reason why you need to do either command.  If next was at ADEFGHI and your goal is ADEFGHIB'C' then the only command you need to run is `git checkout next; git cherry-pick ...master`

Comment: David, I think `rebase` followed by `pull --rebase` is self-defeating, since it changes the history in one direction and then goes back the other way. The real question to answer before you run any commands (other than `git fetch` to update `origin/*`) is: What do I want the history to look like when I'm done? Once you know that, then the actions you take should lead towards that goal.

Comment: It turned out my understanding of rebase was wrong, thanks to all these comments I believe it should be fine now. I am really grateful to all of you!

Answer (score 4):

Start with the very simple steps for rebasing your branch with the master;
Name;

```
git-rebase
```

Synopsis;

```
git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
        [<upstream>] [<branch>]
git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] [--exec <cmd>] [--onto <newbase>]
        --root [<branch>]
git rebase --continue | --skip | --abort | --edit-todo
```

Description;
Assume the following history exists and the current branch is "sample":

```
 A---B---C sample
         /
    D---E---F---G master
```

From this point, the result of either of the following commands:

```
git rebase master
git rebase master sample
```

would be:

```
A'--B'--C' sample
                 /
    D---E---F---G master
```

**NOTE**: The latter form is just a short-hand of `git checkout sample` followed by `git rebase master`. When rebase exits sample will remain the checked-out branch.

If the upstream branch already contains a change you have made (e.g., because you mailed a patch which was applied upstream), then that commit will be skipped. For example, running ‘git rebase master` on the following history (in which A’ and A introduce the same set of changes, but have different committer information):

```
A---B---C sample
         /
    D---E---A'---F master
```

will result in:

```
 B'---C' sample
              /
D---E---A'---F master
```

All these were the diagramatic understanding of the rebase process. 
Once you resolve the conflicts being found after typing `git rebase master`
resolve the conflicts and type `git add -u` to add the changed codes to the repository.
after that perform the command `git rebase --continue` and continue resolving the conflicts and and repeating the command ;

```
git add -u
```

and

```
git rebase --continue
```

until no conflicts being found.
At last the final command will be ,

```
git push --force origin sample(your branch name)
```

Comment: for external refernce follow https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

Comment: Please realign your diagrams to make it clear

Comment: @Sam,  in your answer, there are git commands i.e., `git rebase [-i | --interactive] [options] ` under `Synopsis` section. Can you tell what is the rule to understand those parameters i.e., what does `|` mean? What does `[...]` mean ? Where are the rules mentioned in the online doc you mentioned in the comment ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't always do git rebase, but when I do, I use this "[hammer](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/if_all_you_have_is_a_hammer,_everything_looks_like_a_nail)":

```
o---o---o---o---o  A
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  B
                       \
                        o---o---o  C

git rebase -r B C --onto A    # C should be branch, not hash

o---o---o---o---o  A
    |            \
    |             o'--o'--o'  C
     \
      o---o---o---o---o  B
```

No more stressing about what is the best way to do git rebase for each case ("Should I use `rebase -i`? Should I use `cherry-pick`?") and spending time looking them up.

Of course this is not for everyone, like for example, in a case where we want to split a commit, some people don't like ["doing a bunch of funky work on a new branch"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6217156/9157799). But some people, like me, ["have a phobia of interactive approaches"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66973746/9157799).

> Fear not the man who does 1000 ways of rebase once, but fear the man who does one way of rebase 1000 times. ~Not Bruce Lee