# Any way to know I'm perfectly mirroring an upstream branch?

Tags: git, rebase

My group has a policy that only one person can change the `master` branch on GitHub. He is a Git guru and does complicated commit management on `origin/master`.

Others have been told to use (after INSURING I'm on the master branch):

```
git pull --rebase origin master
```

to insure that we are mirroring `origin` perfectly. However, I know I've forgotten the `--rebase` occasionally. Now I'm wondering, is my local `master` out of sync with the one on `origin`?

Does the above command only succeed if they are in sync? If not what can I do?

Comment: I recommend avoiding `git pull` entirely. Run `git fetch`, then look at what got fetched, then decide what you want to do. In this case it's always `git rebase`, which makes the decision easy, and makes it possible to use `git pull` directly, but that's kind of a bad habit, in my opinion: it's like assuming your gun is never loaded, and using the trigger to take it out of the holster. :-)

Comment: so, you never commit to master locally?

Comment: Correct - locally master should be readonly

Comment: @DavidH nice to see you again (from iOS IP address) but this time with git rebase :D.  Care to check my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894883/rebase-once-commit-some-changes-then-rebase-again-some-unexpected-conflicts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Checking for updates

The simplest way to see if your local branch is up to date with its remote counterpart is to use `git fetch` followed by `git status`.

[`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) updates the information about remote branches, but doesn't update their local counterparts.

[`git status`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-status) shows information about current condition of a branch and working tree. If it is up to the date with the remote, it should say

```
On branch x
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/x'.
```

where `x` would be `master` in your specific case.

On the other hand, if your branch is not up to date, because you added a single commit, for example, it will say

```
On branch x
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/x' by 1 commit.
```

---

## What does `git pull --rebase` do

[`git pull`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull), is actually a shortcut for `git fetch` followed by [`git merge`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge). With `--rebase` modifier, instead of `git merge` [`git rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is used.

In short, `git merge` and `git rebase` both apply changes from one branch to another, but they differ in the way they do that. You might want to check out the documentation or the following SO answers for more info: [`git merge`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14961255/how-does-git-merge-work-in-details), [`git rebase`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566503/5670873).

Answer (score 1):

If you do not specify `--rebase`, you will merge the `master` branch of upstream `origin` (i.e. `origin/master`) into your currently checked branch. If you specify `--rebase`, your changes will be replayed on top of `origin/master`. The end result should be identical.

If you tend to forget to specify `--rebase`, then you can also enable it with a config option: `git config pull.rebase true`. With this option enabled, each time you pull, your changes will be rebased instead of merged.

---

To answer the title of your question: run `git log HEAD..origin/master` (after syncing histories with `git fetch`). If it does not show any commits, your work is up-to-date with origin. If it shows commits, then there are commits in `origin/master` which are not yet integrated into your local working copy.