# Rebase once, commit some changes then rebase again, some unexpected conflicts

Tags: git, git-merge, rebase

I rebased my commits onto the integration branch, then added some commits. Then I found the integration branch has new commits so I decided to rebase again. But to my surprise this time rebase had quite some conflicts.

I further checked where did those conflicts come from and was surprised again. The conflicts were actually the newer commit modified the old one on the integration branch that I already rebased the first time! See the following picture.

And if I use merge to get the new commits no problem at all!

In the integration branch **91ba229 & c4a3755** both modified the same file.
[image: In integration branch]

The first time rebase
[image: 1st time rebase]
The second time rebase since I want to get commits 5997579 & ed2d5b2, conflicts! Because **c4a3755** was applied again and conflicted with the result I got from **91ba229** !. But why?

Why did git apply commit c4a3755 again?

BTW, the blue line is my own branch, I didn't push it to the remote server and I only did what I described in my own branch.

[image: 2nd rebase]

--------------------- update -------------------

I found some clue but I still need some input. So after 1st rebase, my commits did not sit on top of int branch, but the other way around, i.e. the int branch commits sit on top of my commits. I have not figure out why, but it is the reason for the conflicts on the 2nd rebase.

Because instead of letting int branch commits become my base, 2 branches still had the old base. Then when applying the 2nd rebase, all the commits from int branch were applied again. Hence the conflicts.

Comment: Why would you rebase the same commits again? This will obviously lead to conflicts, since different commits touch the same lines in the same files. Which commands did you exactly use?

Comment: As I said I found the int branch has newer commits 5997579 & ed2d5b2 and I want to get them

Comment: Which commands did you exactly use to rebase your branch?

Comment: I use sourctree ui, but it should be just git rebase

Comment: @Qiulang You should never rebase a shared branch `but never rebase anything you’ve pushed somewhere.` [rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Rebasing)

Comment: @smarber I only did it on my own branch so I don't understand your words. See my update.

Comment: @Qiulang `I rebased my commits onto the integration branch`, I must have misunderstood this sentence.