# Git merge develop branch into feature branch

Tags: git, git-merge, git-flow

i'm a git newbie and i'm having difficulties with merging.

Using git-flow, we have a master and a develop branch. Each feature we develop has a proper branch ( let's call it DEV-738 ).
While i develop my feature, another developer works on another branch ( let's call it DEV-750 ) and when their feature is finished it goes into develop. 
I use to merge develop into feature branch, so when my feature will be completed ( i worked on it for about 4 months ) i'm going to encounter less problems. Unfortunately, merging develop into my feature branch causes some issues. I' ve spent 4 days refactoring a function using async/await, and other improvements, and when i've merge develop into my branch my refactor vanished, restoring the old version of the function.
What can I do to prevent issues of this kind in future ?

Thanks

Comment: I'd probably start with investigating 'git rebase' and rebasing your feature branch back off the development branch

Comment: Try having a look at rebasing or continue to use merge, but use GUI for it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563319/git-rebase-basics
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666089/whats-the-difference-between-git-merge-and-git-rebase/25267150

Comment: Also: As long as you've commited the async/await refactoring, you can still recover it.

Comment: Did you get merge conflicts? If so, how did you resolve them? I would probably reset your branch back to before that merge, and redo the merge, assuming you haven't just continued to work after the merge.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen No, the strange thing is that i had no conflicts.

Comment: @Tom yes luckly i had committed my changes so i can recover it, but i'm finding that i had issues in a lot of files and find all the missing new part can be challenging

Comment: What did your merge command look like? From my experience with git, there is an explanation to the behavior you're seeing, it's just not evident from your question and comments what that explanation is yet.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen i've used sourcetree, i never looked at the command it gave :/

Answer (score 2):

There’s no way to avoid all merge conflicts and issues but I will give you some advice that can help you with your workflow dealing with conflicts is as simple as possible.

1. `git pull` the master branch every day.
2. `git rebase master` often. When you know that other developers are working on the same code and have had changes merged, rebase. This is also an alternative to merging master onto your feature that will reduce the commit history mess.
3. Things don’t “vanish”. Learn about `git reflog` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog) and how it can help you through mistakes.
4. Learn about `git rerere` [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rerere) and how it can help you avoid repeating work when you encounter merge conflicts.