# How to rebase branch

Tags: git, github, gitlab

I have 2 branches: 4 and 5, which represent 4 and 5 versions of my application (5 is continuation of 4). By my fault I created new branch from branch 5 (instead of 4) and do one commit. How to change my branch in that way: ostensibly I created my branch from branch 4 and added one commit?

Now:

```
4 ->
 \
  5 ->
   \
   my branch with one commit ->
```

I want:

```
 my branch with one commit ->
 /
4 ->
 \
  5 ->
```

Comment: might this help you [git rebase](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11566503/20320091)

Comment: I was the downvoter but I see you've usefully upgraded your question. I've removed my downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply run

```
git rebase 5 my-branch --onto 4
```

Comment: Thank you, it works! Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

## A. Rebase --onto

The official https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase covers exactly this scenario:

> Here is how you would transplant a topic branch based on one branch to another, to pretend that you forked the topic branch from the latter branch, using `rebase --onto`.
>
> First let’s assume your topic is based on branch next. For example, a feature developed in topic depends on some functionality which is found in next.
>
> ```
> o---o---o---o---o  master
>      \
>       o---o---o---o---o  next
>                        \
>                         o---o---o  topic
> ```
>
> We want to make topic forked from branch master; for example, because the functionality on which topic depends was merged into the more stable master branch. We want our tree to look like this:
>
> ```
> o---o---o---o---o  master
>     |            \
>     |             o'--o'--o'  topic
>      \
>       o---o---o---o---o  next
> ```
>
> We can get this using the following command:
>
> `git rebase --onto master next topic`

## B. No rebase option

The steps below are more manual but their beauty is that they are very very simple to understand.

#### I. Get commit X to branch 4

```
> git checkout 4 
> git cherry-pick commitX
```

#### II. Get rid of commit X from branch 5

Option 1. `> git reset HEAD~1 --hard`

Option 2. `> git revert commitX`