# Undo git stash pop without saving stash

Tags: git

I popped a stash which led to some unintended consequences. Fortunately the stash contents weren't very important. The last commit SHA (pre-pop) was `b1a6d2919dc8a8e80122466cf8662196102ba2d4`

Is there some way to easily reverse this pop using this SHA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to discard the STASH entirely. try `git reset --hard <SHA>`

Comment: I wonder if this will work as I currently show "nothing to commit, working directory clean" ... post POP

Comment: this is not a commit it will reset your current HEAD to the commit <SHA>. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english

Comment: I thought when you popped a stash it applied the stash as uncommited changes? Or is that handled differently?  This is my confusion..

Comment: you are right, popped stash will be applied as uncommitted changes.

Comment: Hmm.. So why do I see nothing to commit message.. while at the same time having changes made to my repo?  I tried looking in gitg for the modifications, but cannot see anything but my last real commit. I am so confused.

Comment: my guess, either the stash is overlapping with one of your previous commit, or you have configured git to ignore changes from it.

Comment: Hmm, well, I have just re-cloned my repository. Fortunately that seems to have fixed the issues. Interestingly the stash is gone completely, so I guess this wasn't saved to my remote repo.