# How can i completely undo git commit just done

Tags: git, version-control

I did commit on my branch.

I accidently added `.tar.gz` files in it which i want to ignore.

Then i did this

`git reset --soft HEAD^`

Now my commit is gone

1. Modified files are as it is
2. But the untracked files are now being shown as new file

How can i go back to state where the new files come as untrcaked file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Whats the difference between git reset --mixed, --soft, and --hard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528245/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-mixed-soft-and-hard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `git reset --soft` only moves `HEAD`, but don't reset the index.

A `git reset @^` would moves `HEAD` *and* reset the index, making those files untracked again.

More on those `reset` options at "[Can you explain what “git reset” does in plain english?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530073/6309)".

See also a good illustration in "[Difference between git reset soft, mixed and hard](http://davidzych.com/2014/05/24/difference-between-git-reset-soft-mixed-and-hard/)": what you want is to reset HEAD and index, not the working tree.

[image: http://davidzych.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/reset-wc-changed-580x136.png]

---

The [OP user3646965](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3646965/user3646965) asks in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24094089/how-can-i-completely-undo-git-commit-just-done/24094189#comment37162700_24094189):

I have already executed `git reset --soft`, can I do `git reset @^` or it will go back one more commit?

Then you can do a reset for the files only (not HEAD, which already references the right commit)

```
cd /path/to/folder/containing/tar.gz_files
git reset -- *.tar.gz
```

Note the **[double-dash (`--`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)** between the git command and the files.

Comment: i have already executed `git reset --soft` can i do `git reset @^` or it will go back one more commit

Comment: @user3646965 I have edited the answer to address your comment.

Comment: thanks, but i have tar files in many subdirs  not a single folder. will that work if execute in root folder

Comment: @user3646965 I don't think it would work recursively. Better to run a classic find command, and pipe its result to a git reset command.

Comment: thanks Von , Does it mean that there is no way to reset all new files to untracked state from my scenario , . I meean not only tar.gz but is there any way i can untrack all new files from my state

Comment: @user3646965 I believe that a simple git reset (from the root folder, no parameters) would be enough to reset everything.

Answer (score 0):

You can't actually delete files via a git reset, which means if you've added new files in your recent commit, even if you do, `git reset --hard HEAD~1`, the files that were added in your last commit won't be deleted. This is an essential and necessary precaution in git. What if, in the hope of restoring your directory to `HEAD~1` git accidentally deletes untracked files that were *not meant to be deleted*?

You can do `git reset --hard HEAD~1` to restore the state of the existing files. But if you've added new files in your latest commit, you've to delete it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`git reset filename` will reset the state of `filename` to whatever it is at the currently commit — i.e., it will unstage a file.