# What does this "git reset" command do?

Tags: git

I was going to unstage a file, but instead of typing:

```
git reset file.sh
```

I typed:

```
git reset file.sh head
```

And the output was:

```
Unstaged changes after reset:
M       path/file1
M       path/file2
M       path/file2
....
^C
```

I know from git documentation that *git reset* has three forms

```
git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>...
git reset (--patch | -p) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>...]
git reset [--soft | --mixed | --hard | --merge | --keep] [-q] [<commit>]
```

But my command don't match any of the three forms.

*My question is:* what happened here? And Why the command operated on all my repository?

*EDIT:* Actually, *file.sh* exists, but *head* don't. If I use

```
git reset existing.file nonexisting.file
```

it will change the index on *existing.file* and will ignore the second file, and show the full list of unstaged file (normal, but resulted in a bit of panic).

If I type:

```
git reset nonexisting.file existing.file
```

it will fail. http://paste.ubuntu.com/12780596/.

Thanks to @sehe to pointing to the correct solution.

Comment: The output says it. It unstages the changes (to the named paths)

Comment: Ok, but what about the parameters I provided? Did it just ignored the "file.sh" and "head" parts?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you explain what "git reset" does in plain english?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/can-you-explain-what-git-reset-does-in-plain-english)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It just ignored the `head` part (assuming that's not a file).

To force git to interpret arguments as paths (e.g. when unstaging a file deletion), use `--`

```
git reset HEAD -- some/path
```

Comment: And what about the "file.sh" parameter? It was ignored too? If this is true, git ignored everything after "reset" and started unstaging my whole working copy?

Comment: I don't know. Give use complete steps to reproduce and I'll tell you.

Comment: Just take a repository with some changed files and run "git reset file.sh head". You'll see that instead of reporting invalid parameters, or trying to reset two files, named "file.sh" and "head" it will reset all files.

Comment: The output: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12775919/ - nothing gets ignored. The output message suggests exactly what I did. Check `git config -l | grep alias` maybe? Or `type git` etc.

Comment: This is the correct answer: `git reset` treats all otherwise-unknown arguments as paths.  If you `git reset` a path that's not in the index, that's a no-op: `git reset arglebargle` does nothing to the index  All the rest of the output is a result of `git reset` doing `git status` after it's finished resetting.

Comment: I'm very sorry, @sehe, _file.sh_ actually *exists*, just _head_ don't. http://paste.ubuntu.com/12780492. Also, the bit that confused (and scared me) was the list of all unstaged files. But it does that even when I used "git reset" correctly. Apparently, if the first argument exists as a file it will accept other arguments as paths as consider them as no-op, as torek said. If the first argument (after reset) don't exist it fails: http://paste.ubuntu.com/12780546. Sorry for misreporting the initial problem.