# Lost all my changes after git rebase --skip

Tags: git

I was working on a branch, after I commited my changes and tried to push them it said that I had diverged and needed to pull the most recent changes.

I did `git pull --rebase` which caused an rebase conflict. I couldt identify where the problem was. So I did `git rebase --skip` which seems to have reverted my changes to a version that is behind my commit.

Is it possible to reset to my commit that I tried to push? I did `git reflog` to find the commit ID. And then I tried `git reset *commitID*` But it does not seem to work. It does not reset. What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to revert Git repository to a previous commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114095/how-to-revert-git-repository-to-a-previous-commit)

Answer (score 0):

I did a `git reset --hard *comitID*`. Still dont know why a "normal" reset didnt work.

Comment: You can learn more about git reset at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2530073/20371 . In particular, a 'normal' reset didn't change your working files because that's the intended behaviour of git, to avoid overwriting people's work. If you're _sure_ you want to, you would use `git reset --hard COMMIT`.

Comment: I concur: what you call "normal" reset implies the `--mixed` command-line option, which is documented.