# react-scripts failed to run npm run build on azure deploy

Tags: reactjs, azure, github

I am trying to deploy an app to azure static web apps, a reactjs application, but im getting something really weird in the github actions.

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

./src/screens/Support/Support.jsx
Cannot find file '../../components/faq/FAQ' in './src/screens/Support'.
```

it says it cannot find this file... but its there. locally it works, if i run `npm run build` locally it works, only when im trying to deploy via github actions does it error out in this way.. why?

Comment: Turns out the file in source control was named differently. it was `faq.jsx` when in the code it was looking for a file called `FAQ.jsx` I know i renamed it locally, but the source control (that being `github`) should've also changed names after i made the commit and push... i find it strange that it didnt do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Turns out the file in source control was named differently. it was `faq.jsx` when in the code it was looking for a file called `FAQ.jsx` I know i renamed it locally, but the source control (that being `github`) should've also changed names after i made the commit and push... i find it strange that it didnt do that

Thank you [ghost](https://github.com/ghost). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

You can run the following commands:

```
git reset HEAD~1
git pull
add/commit/push
```

You can refer to [Push command successful but no changes reflected on Remote Repository file/s.](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/issues/1114#issuecomment-299100560)
 and [In plain English, what does "git reset" do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530060/in-plain-english-what-does-git-reset-do)