# How to get git to overwrite unfound local changes?

Tags: git

Currently git is stuck in a loop. It can't merge because of local changes. I can't stash local changes because none are found.

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull
remote: Counting objects: 5, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
remote: Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (5/5), done.
From https://private/url/project/
   e56777c..fac7619  master     -> origin/master
Updating e56777c..fac7619
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git pull
Updating e56777c..fac7619
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

$ git stash
No local changes to save

$ git fetch

$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is behind 'origin/master' by 1 commit, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)
nothing to commit, working directory clean

$ git stash
No local changes to save

$ git merge
Updating e56777c..fac7619
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting

$ git stash
No local changes to save
```

Trying the accepted answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/force-git-to-overwrite-local-files-on-pull), doesn't work. I get the following error:

```
$ git fetch --all
Fetching origin

$ git reset --hard origin/master
error: Entry 'ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
```

Someone is able to reliably [reproduce and fix the last error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1634115/whats-the-difference-between-git-reset-hard-and-git-reset-merge): 'Could not reset index...'  but the workaround they suggest produces the follow error for me:

```
$ git add .

$ git reset --merge fac7619
error: Entry 'ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset' not uptodate. Cannot merge.
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'fac7619'.
```

<strike>Is there anyway to force git to overwrite the ProjectSettings? or ask it why it thinks there are local changes when none are found?</strike>

## Edit:

Ok, after doing `reset --merge`, I did `reset --hard` then `git status` notified me I was behind 1 commit,  This time when I did `git pull` everything merged with no issues.

So, how can the above scenario be avoided? 
Or is this something that is common to multi-OS environments?
My workflow is fairly consistant. I start with a pull, make edits, add, commit, push. But, for this project, sometimes I am on a windows machine, others I am using OSX. I just have not run into this issue in 2 years of using git.

Comment: Are you resolving conflicts?  Is that file ignored?  What is the output of `git status --ignored`?

Comment: `On branch master
 Assembly-CSharp-Editor-vs.csproj
 Assembly-CSharp-Editor.csproj
 Assembly-CSharp-Editor.sln
 Assembly-CSharp-Editor.userprefs
 Assembly-CSharp-vs.csproj
 Assembly-CSharp-vs.sln
 Assembly-CSharp-vs.userprefs
 Assembly-CSharp.csproj
 Assembly-CSharp.sln
 Assembly-CSharp.userprefs
 Assembly-UnityScript-vs.unityproj
 Assembly-UnityScript.unityproj
 Library/
 STVE-csharp.sln
 STVE.sln
 STVE.userprefs

nothing to commit, working directory clean`

Comment: Maybe resolving conflicts is another issue?  it doesn't tell me there are any conflicts, because it can't find local changes.   I am thinking for the 30 minutes I have spent on this, it might be easier to just delete local, and re-clone remote.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore error on git pull about my local changes would be overwritten by merge?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14318234/how-to-ignore-error-on-git-pull-about-my-local-changes-would-be-overwritten-by-m)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. remove `ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset` from the git way (simply move it to a different name, say `ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset.my`)
2. perform `git pull`. It should be completed seamlessly this time.
3. compare `ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset` and `ProjectSettings/EditorBuildSettings.asset.my` and decide what version is more correct.

Comment: Thanks. This is much faster than deleting the entire repository.  I think it is ultimately the same as going back 1 commit and forcing a merge. Accepting this answer because it's a quicker solution, than all the reset-fetch nonsense.

Comment: not at all. generally I can't imagine a situation when you need to remove an entire repo. Just don't panic, sit still, think twice and ask questions on SO :)

Comment: Worked as charm!

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing checkout on another branch, and checkout master again, e.g.

```
git checkout origin/master -f
git checkout master -f
```

Then pull it again:

```
git pull
```