# Will git-rm --cached delete another user's working tree files when they pull

Tags: git, git-rm

I wish to stop tracking files but still keep them in my working tree.

I've gathered that `git rm --cached FILE` will let me do that. However, if someone else pulls this change, will *their* local copies be deleted?

Comment: In combination with adding them to your .gitignore, I hope!

Comment: Yes. Which is making me wonder what happens if you add them to gitignore and don't git rm them...

Comment: this surely was discussed in the other questions; what happens is... nothing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, their copies will be automatically deleted.  Imagine if this deletion wouldn't happen--then working copies of all users would be polluted with piles of deleted files, which aren't needed anymore.

However, if the remote users made local changes to these files, they won't be deleted, since `pull` will result in a merge conflict.

As [Jefromi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119963/jefromi) suggests in his comment, while the files are removed at the other users' sides, they can easily be restored--they're under a version-control, aren't they? ;-)  Files could be gotten by `git checkout <revision> -- <files...>`.  As revision you may specify the id of the previous commit, for pull it's saved in `ORIG_HEAD` (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) for details):

```
git checkout ORIG_HEAD -- removed_file
```

Comment: And if the pull doesn't conflict, but they want the files back, all they have to do is `git checkout HEAD^ <path>`.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know.

Fingers crossed I didn't delete any vital xcode files on my colleagues' working directories.

Answer (score 2):

In such a case I would rather ignore them **locally** only :

If they are already tracked :

```
git update-index --skip-worktree FILE
```

If they untracked : add them to your local exclude file

```
echo "FILE" >> .git/info/exclude
```

You can also have global .gitignore if its something you will do for all your repos (e.g. *~)