# cannot push to github: everything up-to-date

Tags: git, github, git-push

On github, I forked an old version of another project. I made some changes and am trying to push them onto my fork on github. I commited the changes locally, then tried git push, but this simply tells me "Everything up-to-date". When I browse the project on github, however, nothing has changed: it still shows the files (from the latest version) on my fork, unmodified. How can I push the changes to my github account?

(I realize this isn't much information...what else can I say? I have a feeling that it may be because I'm modifying the files directly in (home)/git/(project)...?)

Comment: Check if your are on correct branch.
git log --graph --all --decorate --pretty=oneline and 
git remote show origin
may be useful

Comment: What is the output of `git branch -v` and `git remote -v`?

Comment: `Everything up-to-date` means nothing has been pushed (because nothing has been added), did you `git add` and `git commit` before your `git push`?

Comment: Ahh, `git branch -v` indicates that my commit was on (no branch). As for the add, I initially commited the changes through Eclipse (with the git plugin)...when I do `git add` from the command line, it doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> git branch -v indicates that my commit was on (no branch). As for the add, I initially commited the changes through Eclipse (with the git plugin)...when I do git add from the command line, it doesn't seem to do anything

That means you are in a [DETACHED HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965676/why-did-git-detach-my-head/3965714#3965714) mode.
You can add and commit, but from the upstream repo point of view (ie from the GitHub repo), no new commits are ready to be pushed.
You have various ways to include your local (detached `HEAD`) commit back into a branch, which you will be able to push then.
See:

- "[Not currently on any branch + `git commit` + checkout when not in any branch. Did I loose my changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6048425/not-currently-on-any-branch-git-commit-checkout-when-not-in-any-branch-did)"
- "[detached `HEAD` explained](http://gitolite.com/detached-head.html)".
- "[Git: How can I reconcile detached `HEAD` with master/origin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)"
- "[Git Lesson: Be mindful of a detached head](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2011/05/29/life-lesson-be-mindful-of-a-detached-head/)"
- "[Git Tip of the Week: Detached Heads](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/08/git-tip-of-week-detached-heads.html)"

The OP mentions this article in order to fix the situation:
"[git: what to do if you commit to no branch](https://edspencer.net/2009/10/28/git-what-to-do-if-you-commit-to-no-branch/)"

> all we need to do is checkout the branch we should have been on and merge in that commit SHA:

Note that instead of merging the SHA1 that you would have somehow copied, you can memorize it with a script, using `head=$(git rev-parse HEAD)`:
See "[git: reliably switching to a detached HEAD and then restore HEAD later, all from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3467576/6309)".
Then you can merge that detached `HEAD` back to the right branch.

Comment: Yep, this is what I just figured out. [This showed me how to fix it.](http://edspencer.net/2009/10/git-what-to-do-if-you-commit-to-no-branch.html/comment-page-1)

Comment: @KelseyRider I have added a reference to a script which would memorizing the detached HEAD SHA1 for you.

Answer (score 9):

After you change files, you need to

```
git add
```

them prior to

```
git commit
```

.

Comment: He said he commited the changes locally

Answer (score 5):

```
git commit
```

Will show you what files are on your local machine, uncomment what you want to upload and

```
git push origin master
```

Because `git add *` did not work for me (even if it didn't returned errors).

Comment: Instead of an asterisk (*), you use a period (.) to denote everything.  Ex. git add .

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why people are down voting the guy with the correct answer.  For me adding my email and name did resolve the issue.  Although the commands are not correct.

```
git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the `git commit -m` command

In my case I had just forgotten to add the `-` before the m

When you do that the terminal outputs an error as follows
`error: pathspec 'm' did not match any file(s) known to git`
`error: pathspec 'TESTING' did not match any file(s) known to git`

But stil when you try to `git push` you won't get any error but the output will be

`Everything up-to-date`

The order should be: 
`git status`

`git add .` *Thats if you want to add the entire changes to be commited*

`git commit -m "Your Comments"`

Answer (score -2):

In recent git version have to configer user details git config -g user.name "name"

```
git config -g user.email "ab@mil.com"
```

This resolved my problem