# git source control not working with visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github

I have been using Git source control for a while now and I use Git bash + Git source control with visual studio but lately git source control with visual studio does not seem to work.

When i do Get pending changes then it does not show me anything but when I go to git bash then I can see couple of dirty files. Also, it does not show me current branch in visual studio. It seems like some setting might have gone wrong and visual studio is somehow detached with gitbash.

I also tried uninstalling Gi source control for visual studio and installing it again but without any help at all.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try with gitExtension? (https://github.com/spdr870/gitextensions) And did you check if you are in a detached HEAD mode? (http://stackoverflow.com/a/11085465/6309 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)

Comment: I am not in detached mode actually. From my GitBash, I can actually create and checkout branches and feature finish. All the regular activities. So I think my Git repo is OK. Something is exclusively wrong with how visual studio interacts with Git.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use git extensios:
https://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/