# Github not checking if local repo has changed

Tags: github, synchronization, github-for-windows

I recently re-installed my computer,
and now I'm encountering problems with github for windows (I'll be using GFW in the rest of this text). it say's that my local repo is in sync, but even if I change things, delete files, or add files it keeps saying that it is in sync.

It does check if I make changes on a different computer and push them. but syncing then won't work, so I went to shell

there I can commit (shows in GFW that there are commits ready to be pushed), sync button in GFW still doesn't work (showing that there are problems, and I should continue in git shell). When I commit in shell says that there are changes , insertions, and deletions

Then when I want to push it says `Everything up-to-date`.

Anyone got any clue what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are actually on a branch: are your commits made on a branch, or on a "[detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5772192/git-how-can-i-reconcile-detached-head-with-master-origin)"? (more on this at "[cannot push to GitHub: everything up-to-date](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11085465/6309)").

A simple git branch can show you the active branch. If there are none, that would explain why the "sync" button is inactive. You need to [fast-forward your branch to that detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4845505/6309).

Comment: I'm on a normal branch, but the weirdesd part is that the git shell is working fine, the program just doesn't register changes, and is having problems pushing / pulling / switching branches / ...