# Recovering from a failed rebase

Tags: git, git-svn, rebase

I'm using `git svn` to get some git goodness with the company-mandated svn server. I just had a rebase go horribly awry, and I"m trying to figure out the best way to recover.

Here's what happened:

1. To start with, I had this

   ```
   ---1 (master)
       \--B--C--D--E (feature/fix-widgets)
   ```
2. So then I did `git checkout master` and then `git svn rebase` on master to pull down those commits. I did not anticipate any conflicts between my feature branch and the master, because the changes were in a totally different folder. So at this point, I think I have this:

   ```
   ---1--2--3--4 (master)
       \--B--C--D--E (feature/fix-widgets)
   ```

   Where `1--2--3--4` are commits pulled in from svn.
3. Next I do `git checkout feature/fix-widgets` and then `git rebase master`. There's immediately a conflict, and some things that don't add up, so I decide to slink away and look at things more carefully. I do `git rebase --abort`, hoping this will restore me to where I was before the rebase.
4. I do `git rebase --abort` and receive the following message

   ```
   $ git rebase --abort
     error: git checkout-index: unable to create file somedir/somefile.cs (Permission denied)
     fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'be44daa05be39f6dd0d602486a598b63b6bd2af7'.
   ```
5. Now I'm not sure what to do. `git status` shows that I'm on `feature/fix-widgets`, but I have a whole bunch of staged changed, and a large number of untracked files, which were previously committed. I'd be fine if I could get back `E`.

Comment: I encountered this very same issue today -- I'm guessing you were using git on Windows, that lovely operating system that thought sharing locks was a good idea. My guess is that the reason it choked on somedir/somefile.cs was that it was open somewhere... this was the cause of my failed rebase. Closing all the open programs I could find, resetting as per the chosen answer, then rebasing, worked without a problem.

Comment: +1 for well written question that saved me from crying.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You should have a look at **[`ORIG_HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)**

> `ORIG_HEAD` is previous state of `HEAD`, set by commands that have possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them.
>   It is less useful now that Git has reflog: `HEAD@{1}` is roughly equivalent to `ORIG_HEAD` (`HEAD@{1}` is always last value of `HEAD`, `ORIG_HEAD` is last value of `HEAD` before dangerous operation)

So try this [`git reset`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) to get back to before any rebase:

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

Comment: Well that was easy. I did a reset, and then just dumbly tried to rebase again, and it worked. *shrug*

Comment: @notJim: true, but it can be useful to keep `ORIG_HEAD` in mind when doing those commands. It can come in handy.