# Git: Recover from failed rebase

Tags: git, reset, rebase

I just tried to rebase one of my feature-branches and something went wrong - now i am trying to figure out how to undo this.

Being on my feature-branch i simply did a: `git rebase develop` after committing a bugfix on `develop` which i wanted in the feature-branch as well.
This gave me:

```
$ git rebase develop
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Rename from '.git/HEAD.lock' to '.git/HEAD' failed. Should I try again? (y/n)? n

error: Couldn't set HEAD
fatal: Cannot update the ref 'HEAD'.
could not detach HEAD
```

Well, now i see a bunch of staged files on this branch, but it seems that all commits on this branch are still intact (at least i am not missing one :)

I want to revert this branch to how it looked like before the rebase-attempt. Unfortunately it seems that `ORIG_HEAD` was not correctly set before the rebase, since i can see it being shown next to a commit on another feature-branch (which i rebased before trying to rebase this feature-branch).

Is a reset to the last visible commit on my current feature-branch the way to go?

--qu

Comment: Just linking for future ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660521/recovering-from-a-failed-rebase

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git reflog` to see the what commit it was, copy commit number for there and do `git reset --hard <number>`