# Concurrent operations on a Git repo

Tags: git

If two processes try to do something to a Git repository at the same time, is there a chance of corrupting the data? Or does Git have some sort of locking mechanism to prevent this?

More specifically, what happens if `git fetch` and `git gc` are run at the same time? If one of them fails, then that's a risk I can live with. But if the repo gets borked, then that's not OK.

Comment: Regarding `git gc` specifically, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/41664365/6309

Answer (score 0):

Git repo's make a `.HEAD.lock` file when doing operations, However from testing your case of running `git fetch` and `git gc` at the same time it seems like this does not come into affect. I would proceed with caution when doing this.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How exactly did you test this, and what happened?

Comment: Some operations make a `.head.lock`, I mainly know this because it bothers me greatly when I have SourceTree open and I try and commit from the command line, This mainly happens upon write actions. You can see this going wrong here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9481735/git-recover-from-failed-rebase