# List changed files in git post-merge hook

Tags: git, githooks

Is there a way for a post-merge hook get a list of all the files that were changed by a merge, even if it was a fast-forward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet at that point is going to be the reflogs. If you've just fast-forwarded, the first line of HEAD's reflog will look like this:

```
63e21fb HEAD@{0}: merge origin/master: Fast-forward
```

So you should be able to print just the first line (`git reflog -n 1`), check if it matches `merge .*: Fast-forward$`, and if so, do `git diff HEAD@{1} HEAD`. (You do want to look at the reflogs to verify that there was a fast-forward merge, probably, unless you can be confident from your script that it's the only possibility now.)

Comment: Perhaps I'm missing something, but along those lines, why not just do `git diff --name-only HEAD@{1} HEAD`?

Comment: @Mark: Amended to address that.

Comment: Ah, thanks to both of you. I didn't know about the `@{}` notation.

Comment: I was thinking that the diff will still produce sensible results if it was a non-fast-forward merge, so so you don't need to check whether it was a ff at all.

Comment: @Mark: I guess I was thinking about corner cases, e.g. evil merges, where you can get more complete diff output with `git show <merge commit>`, but you're right, it doesn't matter if you're only looking at the list of changed files.

Answer (score 14):

The right Git command to list the changed files is [`diff-tree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff-tree)

Also the `ORIG_HEAD` and `HEAD` [shortcuts](/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git) may be used:

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id ORIG_HEAD HEAD
```

(see also: [List all the files for a commit in Git](/questions/424071/list-all-the-files-for-a-commit-in-git))

**[upd]**

Perhaps it is better to use `HEAD@{1}` in place of `ORIG_HEAD`. I.e.:

```
git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id HEAD@{1} HEAD
```

In case of `git pull --ff-only` command, when many commits can be added, `HEAD@{1}` (inside post-merge hook) gives the last commit before this command, while `ORIG_HEAD` gives just `HEAD^` commit (at least in Git 2.1.4).

Comment: remember that ORIG_HEAD and HEAD@{1} are not always the same thing.  HEAD@{1} is always the last commit while ORIG_HEAD is the last from what Git considers a dangerous operation.  See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/967611/647292