# How to take selective action after a pull based on the files that have change?

Tags: git

I would like to create some derived data after doing a pull from GitHub.  The repo may have none or many items that need to be built based on what has changed,  so I would like to be selective.  My first thought was to use a `Makefile` and a `post-merge` hook,  but unless I am totally missing something `make` will not work since all the timedate stamps will be meaningless after the pull.

My next thought, based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18957885/2612259), is to analyze the results of  `git diff-tree -r --name-only --no-commit-id HEAD@{1} HEAD` in a post-merge hook and take action based on that analysis.

This seems like something that should come up often but I have not seen recommend idiomatic approach to this.  Does anyone know of know of such an approach or have a better recommendation?  The answer I am referencing is almost 10 years old

### Update

Quentin's comment made me realize the part I was *totally missing* was that pull does not alter the time / date stamps of files that are not changed.  I must have been thinking about after a clone.  So I guess `make` should work. The times and dates may not match the time and date of the actual file change but will reflect when they were pulled,  so I think `make` still is an option.

Comment: That solution sounds good to me, what do you dislike about it? Edit: actually, the simple `make` solution should work since Git will not touch unchanged files.

Comment: hmmm ... @Quentin I guess I was missing something.  I must have been thinking about when you do a clone all the files are get the time / date stamp of the time the clone was created,  so I guess make should work.