# Using previous pull on git

Tags: git

I frequently do a git pull on a live server. If my website fails after a git pull, what is the command to go back to previous version of website which is stable?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `git pull --ff-only` to perform only fast-forward pulls (i.e. no conflicts and no merges necessary). Then you don't have to reset at all.

Answer (score 6):

```
git reset --hard ORIG_HEAD
```

or

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

(see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git))

Comment: Or `git reset --hard HEAD@{1}`, which is easier to generalize (e.g. if you want to go back past two pulls).

Comment: How about seeing the logs and going back to a specific commit?

Comment: @user845480: `git log` to check the logs, then copy-paste the SHA1 from there to get `git reset --hard <sha1>`.

Comment: Thanks. When I do git reset --hard <sha1>, then that becomes my HEAD I think. I see it at the very top of the list when I do git log so I lost the commit after it? How can I go back to see the hashes after <sha1> i.e. when I saw them on first git log command?