# Can't push to Github repo

Tags: git, github

Been using Git for a while now but only just created a Github account. I've setup a repo but I keep getting errors when I try to push to it.

> error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/username/myrepo.git'
>   hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
>   hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
>   hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
>   hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
>   hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

I've tried doing`git pull` but then I get **Pull is not possible because you have unmerged files.**

Any ideas?

Comment: It means that you're still in a merge locally - you need to resolve the merge before you go to pull.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Pull is Not Possible, Unmerged Files](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15127078/456814).

Answer (score 0):

check the diff between your stuff and the remote repository http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff and then merge the files that you want merged, or if you don't have anything that you need in your local you can `git checkout .` to remove your changes and then `git pull` to pull the remote repository as it is.

Comment: I've sorted it - deleted the repo, made a new one and it works!

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of solutions to [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15127078/git-pull-is-not-possible-unmerged-files) that I think would apply here. The easiest one is to back up your local repo to some other folder, then run:

```
git fetch origin
git reset --hard origin/master
```

The answer I linked to also has a technical explanation of why.

Aside from that, `git status` is your best friend.