# Using Git to undo deleting folder

Tags: git

I deleted the whole migrate folder in Rails. I meant to just delete one file. I have everything pushed onto GitHub, but I don't know how to retrieve the files.

I'm not sure how to get the files back. The revision history option is greyed out so I can't do that.

Comment: I assume your migration folder was part of you repository then? And you have `git` setup to interact with github? If so, do a new `git clone ...` of the repository on your system and it will retrieve everything. I would also highly recommend that if you care about the data you have on your hard drive, you should be performing regular backups to another storage medium.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477702/undo-delete-in-git