# Files are all gone. I deleted all the files with git rm -r *

Tags: git, github, laravel-5

IS there a way to retrieve back my laravel app  files after I typed

> git rm -r *

I just want to delete the files that I just deleted in the directory with

> git rm data.txt

But all of them. Then I mistakenly typed

> git rm -r *

Now most of my app directories are all gone.

these are now what's left

[image: App FOlder left]

Comment: `git reset --hard` will get you back to your last-checked-out state

Comment: @jthill. How can I remove all the deleted files in the directory with just single typing Like 

> git rm <all the deleted files>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undo delete in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9477702/undo-delete-in-git)

Comment: @jthill's answer is right how can i Upvote

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comment by Inertia, `git reset --hard` would return your index and working tree to the last committed state. You could also do a `git reset HEAD` to get your index back and then `git checkout [files or folders]` if you want to keep any other uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 0):

In order to restore just one specific deleted file, make sure to add `--` before the file name:

```
 git reset -- path/to/deleted/file && git checkout -- path/to/deleted/file
```

The `--` is needed as a qualifier for a file, as git would not know whether it's a file or a branch.