# egit dead branch, add to index not working, cannot checkout

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Some files where added to Branch A in eclipse, however I cannot add them to the index with Team->Add to Index. Nothing happens.
 
Toolbar "Add to Git Index": Nothing happens.
 
The icons before the file names stay untracked.
When I want to commit they are not in the list. 
When I want to switch to branch B, I get checkout conflicts for these files.
What could be preventing these files from being added to the index?

I have updated to Luna, the problem is still there

I have done some more tries: In branch A, if I add a new file, I get a plain icon in front of it and it cannot be added to the index.
In branch B the new file gets the icon with the question mark and can be added to the index.
It seems like branch A is a dead branch. Any git-gardeners out there know to revive it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry it was a duplicate question after all, the same question with answer is here: [Can't add new file to repository in EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808656/cant-add-new-file-to-repository-in-egit?rq=1)

It took me a while to find the .gitignore file. But there it was ignoring my whole branch. I suppose I wanted to ignore a file (probably the annoying proguard.txt) and erroneously clicked Team->Ignore for the whole project/branch. The problem is, it is hard to tell from the icons, and there is no way to undo it from the menu: the "Ignore" option in my opinion should change to "Stop Ignoring". So you have to edit or delete the .gitignore file.