# Changes of new Classes in Eclipse are not shown in the git repository

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

I have experienced some issues with Eclipse and EGit.

When I create a new class in my existing repository, it is kind of not linked an changes in this class aren't visible in the unstaged changes in the git view of eclipse.

I have tried to track the new class via the team menu of the right click menu of the class, but didn't find any way of fixing my problem.

I have the latest version of eclipse installed.

Comment: Any chance you have added that path under `.gitignore`?

Comment: @jagad89 oh yeah. Had the full path of the local repository in it. Thanks!

Comment: @jagad89 Would you like to add this as an answer? You could also explain how this can be seen from the (missing) decoration of the file icon.

Comment: Actually I have never used `Egit`, but the problem he explained is a very common mistake.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't add new file to repository in EGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808656/cant-add-new-file-to-repository-in-egit)

Comment: @jagad89 is there a way to push your comment to be an answer? Or do I have to write it myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was, that the full path of the repository was in the gitignore. Deleted the content of it and everything is back fine.