# GIT Preview Checkout or Merge

Tags: git, bash

I want to do a script that help me to release a system by checkout a repo in GIT.

My quest is can I some way test to checkout a branch to identify if I got error without to rely do this on the file-system.

As same, can I on a easy way preview a GIT merge for identify conflict without modify the file-system?

(The full system is run on Linux system if this is to help)

Answer (score 1):

Use `git merge --ff-only` - it will merge branch only if it could be fast forwarded. It means that conflicts are impossible and it will always work (except of course system failures, e.g. out of disk space). Obviously, it means that branches should be not diverged, however in most cases it is so, if not you should do merge with potential conflicts in another repo, keeping the "release repo" untouched.

Another approach here is to use symlinks (linux or ntfs). You should have two repositories `repo1` and `repo2` and a symlink `releaserepo` which will point to one of these. Say, you have `releaserepo`->`repo1`. Now you could update `repo2`, check if all works, then just change symlink to it, next time you will update `repo1` and flip the symlink back. If will avoid all system failures too, because create symlink operation is atomic.

Answer (score 0):

If you checkout a branch, you'll never get an error. The checkout just restores the previous state of the branch.

Things get different, if you want to check merges.

If you have a branch `mybranch` and you want to merge `otherbranch` into it, remember the state of `mybranch` before the merge:

```
git log -1 --oneline
```

This returns the hash of the last commit. Note that hash (e.g. `CAFEBABE`).

Now, try to do the merge:

```
git merge otherbranch
```

If everything works. Fine. If you get any errors and are not willing to resolve them:

```
git reset --hard CAFEBABE
```

This will reset `mybranch` to the state before `git merge` was done.

Instead of remembering the hash `CAFEBABE`, you could also make use of `ORIG_HEAD` as described here: [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)

Comment: Yes you can get errors while checkout as you has local change that not is commited or is out of the repo by gitinrgnor file.

Comment: you don't want to merge uncommitted states