# Git: how to go back to state before git pull

Tags: git, version

I was on `master` branch and i was on some commit i dont remember.

Then i did `git pull` and i got some 20 more commits.

Now i want to undo that want to go to commit where i was before git pull

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
git reset --hard HEAD@{1}
```

it should be previous state of `HEAD`

> ORIG_HEAD is previous state of HEAD, set by commands that have
>   possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them. It is less
>   useful now that Git has reflog: HEAD@{1} is roughly equivalent to
>   ORIG_HEAD (HEAD@{1} is always last value of HEAD, ORIG_HEAD is last
>   value of HEAD before dangerous operation).

from here: [HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)

Answer (score 2):

Running  `git reflog` will give you a list of all the commits that have been pointed to by `HEAD` (`HEAD` is what specifies the current commit you're on e.g. if you're on `master` then `HEAD` will be pointing to the most recent commit on `master`).

It will look something like this:

```
e6832cb HEAD@{0}: pull: Fast-forward
e251737 HEAD@{1}: checkout: moving from my_branch to master 
bb14227 HEAD@{2}: commit: Here's a comment
```

If you've just done the `git pull` and nothing else then the commit you were on before the `git pull` should be the commit to the left of `HEAD@{1}`

From there you can use that commit hash to get back to where you want.

Comment: @Heather's answer is more succinct. Will leave this here as a FYI as to what the HEAD reference is all about